# Set icon for Android application

Tags: android, icons

How can I set an icon for my Android application?

Comment: NOTE, for 2016, simply select "New Image Asset" (find it usually via: right-click on eg. the "mipmap" res item) and then just use the wizard.  Start with one large image and it scales it for you.  See answer by @Justice below.

Comment: Important tip for transparent BG: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37085828/294884

Comment: I'm suggestion (WebApp) [https://android-material-icon-generator.bitdroid.de](https://android-material-icon-generator.bitdroid.de)

Answer (score 736, accepted):

If you intend on your application being available on a large range of devices, you should place your application icon into the different `res/drawable...` folders provided. In each of these folders, you should include a 48dp sized icon:

- `drawable-ldpi` *(120 dpi, Low density screen)* - **36px** x **36px**
- `drawable-mdpi` *(160 dpi, Medium density screen)* - **48px** x **48px**
- `drawable-hdpi` *(240 dpi, High density screen)* - **72px** x **72px**
- `drawable-xhdpi` *(320 dpi, Extra-high density screen)* - **96px** x **96px**
- `drawable-xxhdpi` *(480 dpi, Extra-extra-high density screen)* - **144px** x **144px**
- `drawable-xxxhdpi` *(640 dpi, Extra-extra-extra-high density screen)* - **192px** x **192px**

You may then define the icon in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file as such:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon_name" android:label="@string/app_name" >
.... 
</application>
```

Comment: BTW you can use Inkscape to generate png from SVG. With something like:
`inkscape %logo_file% -e %output_file% %WIDTH% %HEIGHT% --export-background-opacity=0.0`

Comment: You can use a single large icon, though you'll have no control over how the algorithm changes its final appearance. This question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695413/android-designing-different-icons-for-screen-densities

Comment: What should the extension be? `.png`? `.ico`?

Comment: imagine how 512 x 512 will be displayed as 36 x 36? program will pick some pixels from 512 x 512, maybe somehow mix them and display as 36 x 36. There sure will be quantization error, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing. So sure the 36 x 36 image will not be pixel perfect.

Comment: @LiamGeorgeBetsworth where exactly did you find those sizes?

Comment: @aleb http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html - "So, to create an icon for different densities, you should follow the 2:3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the five primary densities (medium, high, x-high, xx-high, and xxx-high respectively). For example, consider that the size for a launcher icon is specified to be 48x48 dp. This means the baseline (MDPI) asset is 48x48 px, and the high-density(HDPI) asset should be 1.5x the baseline at 72x72 px, and the x-high density (XHDPI) asset should be 2x the baseline at 96x96 px, and so on."

Comment: See my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049732/creating-a-new-icon-set-in-android-studio/34740385#34740385 to let Gradle generate the resource files for you.

Comment: See my answer below where you only need to set one image and Android Studio handles the scaling for you.

Comment: _For anyone reading this comment_ - please refer to Arshid's answer below

Answer (score 358):

Add an application launcher icon with automatic sizing.

**(Android studio)**

Go to menu File* → *New* → *Image Assets* → select launcher icon → choose image file.

It will automatically re-size.

Done!

Comment: i don't understand why this isn't the best answer. can someone explain? all the folders and scaled images are created for me

Comment: This explains how to create folders and scaled images. It does not explain how to set any of them to be the app's icon.

Comment: Sorry, my comment is about why I think it is not the best answer. It is a very good answer and helped my solve my icon problem.

Comment: I understand that it will automatically resize but what size do you usually supply? 512x512?

Comment: This is the fastest way and supported right out of the box. Thanks a lot for pointing this out, enjoy some bounty.

Comment: In today's Android Studio I found this menu by right clicking in the browse pane on the left.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ujikit/add-icons-to-the-android-application-from-android-studio-ide-cd1af9348749

Comment: This is the fastest and most reliable way. I don't know why or how the accepted answer got 700+ votes...

Answer (score 216):

I found [this tool](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) the most useful.

1. Upload an image.
2. Download a zip.
3. Extract it into your project.
4. ***Done***

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: This is a super easy way to do it!  My steps were:
1) Create 144x144 image from illustrator file
2) Upload the file
3) Play with settings on website for padding/etc
4) Copy "res" file from .zip from site, paste it in IntelliJ and select "Overwrite Files"

Comment: Do the images go into mitmpa or drawables?

Comment: I don`t understand what to do with this zip :c

Comment: This doesn't give it in `ldpi`

Answer (score 80):

It's better to do this through Android Studio rather than the file browser as it updates all icon files with the correct resolution for each.

To do so go to menu *File* → *New* → *Image Asset*. This will open a new dialogue and then make sure Launcher Icons is selected (Which it is by default) and then browse to the directory of your icon (it doesn't have to be in the project resources) and then once selected make sure other settings are to your liking and hit done.

Now all resolutions are saved into their respective folders, and you don't have to worry about copying it yourself or using tools, etc.

[image]

Don't forget "Shape - none" for a transparent background.

Please don't edit my answer without asking.

Comment: For newer versions of android studio, this is the best answer, +1 from me

Comment: Updated for 2018, should be first

Comment: This is the best answer, because Android Studio will generate all the right assets with the right names. You can start with a single image asset rather than having to manually generate different assets sizes and then trying to figure out where they go in the latest version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 42):

Put your images in `mipmap` folder and set in manifest file...
like as

```
 <application android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" >
 .... 
 </application>
```

**App Folder Directory :**

[image]

**Icon Size & Format :**
[image]

Answer (score 33):

Place your images in drawables folder under either of the three and set it like this.

**Code**

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/your_icon" >
.... 
</application>
```

Comment: which folder which file....

Answer (score 21):

Right click your project, go to **New > Other > Android > Android Icon Set**

Then follow the instructions on the Wizard

Comment: That option doesn't exist on Android Studio.

Comment: I had to click on a file in the project to expand the breadcrumbs at the top.  Then there were different options available when right clicking the project.  New > Image Assets

Answer (score 20):

**1-Create Your icon in Photoshop Or Coreldraw by size 256*256**

> note that use PNG file format if you want to have a transparent icon

**2-Upload Your icon in https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html**

**3-Set your setting on this site** 
[image]

**4-Download the zip file automatically created by the webpage by clicking on download button**
[image]

**5-Extract the zip file and copy res folder to you project library**
[image]

> note that res folder contain all size icon

**6-finally you need to set the manifest to use icon**

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/your_icon" >
.... 
</application>
```

Answer (score 14):

I found all these answers that used to be solid answers to be a bit dated now. I reckon this will be the fate of this answer someday.

Click on your main project, most people would have "app" as their main project name by default. I like to be specific since I have other projects as well.

[your project name|app]->"New"->"Image Asset"

[image: Example of how where to find Image Asset tool in Android Studio]

Then you will get to pick an image. I chose once that wasn't the greatest fit. Notice the tool shows you the "safe zone".

[image: Example of Android Studio's Image Asset Tool]

You can sample the different resolutions. Change the name, etc. The default name is "ic_launcher". I prefer to be expressive with the name so there is no confusion later which ic_launcher this belongs too.

Choose "Next", make changes if you need to, and ultimately "Finish". I found the rest of the tool to be self explanatory. For more info I suggest reading the manual that describes all these settings in more detail: [Android Studio Image Asset Tool Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio)

On "Finish" this will put the files into the respective folders under the expected "res" folder.
[image: Sample output of the Image Asset tool]

The next thing you have to do is have to tell the project that's the icon you want to use. Inside the AndroidManifest.xml do something like the following (using your own name you chose to use above.)

```
     <application
     android:icon="@mipmap/pooflingers_ic_launcher">
```

That's pretty much it, as of today anyway... I am using Android Studio v4.2.1 Let me know when these steps become out of date.

Answer (score 13):

You can simply install an Android studio Martial icons plugin its name is  please check plugin URL [Material Design Icon Generator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/7647-android-material-design-icon-generator) and check this GIF for more details:

[image: Android studio icons plugin]

This is mainly for creating the icons with required sizes, and it will be located directly in its folders.

Answer (score 7):

You have to follow steps like:

- You will see your default icons **`ic_launcher.png`** like:

[image]

- You have to change all the images which are in **mipmap-xxxx** folders.
  First of you have to create your own logo or pick up image that you want to place as icon of launcher and upload here [Android Asset Studio - Icon Generator - Launcher](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html) icons, You will get all the set of mipmap-xxxx and web_icon also from that link.

[image]

- Now you have to copy all the folders which are in side of res folder,

[image]

- Now go to Android Studio **Project -> Right click on res folder -> Paste**. It will prompt you like File **'ic_launcher.png'** already exists in directory, You can press Overwrite all. It will paste/replace images in respective folder.

Now you can run and see your application icon with new image.

Happy Coding :) :)

Comment: I prefer your answer...
Thx for help

Answer (score 6):

1. Choose icon picture copy this pic
2. Paste it into your project's `res/drawable` folder
3. Open manifest file and set
4. Run program

Answer (score 5):

If you have an SVG icon, you can use this [script](https://gist.github.com/deepankarb/e69de4373ebd7067e0fc) to generate your android icon set.

Answer (score 5):

In AndroidManifest change these :

```
android:icon="@drawable/icon_name"
android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon_name"
```

Comment: I liked it, straight to the fact. Thx

Answer (score 4):

## Define the icon for android application

```
<application android:icon="drawable resource">
.... 
</application>
```

<sub>https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html</sub>

---

## If your app available across large range of devices

> You should create separate icons for all generalized screen densities,
>   including low-, medium-, high-, and extra-high-density screens. This
>   ensures that your icons will display properly across the range of
>   devices on which your application can be installed...

[image]

---

## Size & Format

> Launcher icons should be 32-bit PNGs with an alpha channel for
>   transparency. The finished launcher icon dimensions corresponding to a
>   given generalized screen density are shown in the table below.

[image]

---

## Place icon in mipmap or drawable folder

`android:icon="@drawable/icon_name"` or `android:icon="@mipmap/icon_name"`

[**developer.android.com/guide says**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html),

> This attribute must be set as a reference to a drawable resource
>   containing the image (for example "@drawable/icon").

[**about launcher icons android-developers.googleblog.com says,**](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html)

> It’s best practice to place your app icons in mipmap- folders (not the
>   drawable- folders) because they are used at resolutions different from
>   the device’s current density. For example, an xxxhdpi app icon can be
>   used on the launcher for an xxhdpi device.

**[Dianne Hackborn from Google (Android Framework) says](https://plus.google.com/+DianneHackborn/posts/QTA9McYan1L)**,

> If you are building different versions of your app for different
>   densities, you should know about the "mipmap" resource directory. 
>   This is exactly like "drawable" resources, except it **does not
>   participate in density stripping** when creating the different apk
>   targets.

## **[For launcher icons, the AndroidManifest.xml file must reference the mipmap/ location](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html#delete)**

```
<application android:name="ApplicationTitle"
         android:label="@string/app_label"
         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" >
```

Little bit more quoting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32328336/5188159)

1. You want to load an image for your device density and you are going to use it "as is", *without changing its actual size*. In this case you should work with **drawables** and Android will give you the best fitting image.
2. You want to load an image for your device density, but this image *is going to be scaled up or down*. For instance this is needed when you want to show a bigger launcher icon, or you have an animation, which increases image's size. In such cases, to ensure best image quality, you should put your image into **mipmap** folder. What Android will do is, it will try to pick up the image from a higher density bucket instead of scaling it up. This will increase sharpness (quality) of the image.

Fore more you can read [mipmap vs drawable folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmap-vs-drawable-folders)

---

## Tools to easily generate assets

1. [Android Asset Studio by romannurik.github](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)
2. [Android Asset Studio by jgilfelt.github](https://jgilfelt.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html)
3. [Image Asset Studio(from Android Studio)](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html)
4. [Material Icon Generator.bitdroid.de](https://android-material-icon-generator.bitdroid.de/)
5. [Android Material Design Icon Generator Plugin by github.com/konifar](https://github.com/konifar/android-material-design-icon-generator-plugin)
6. [A script to generate android assets from a SVG file](https://gist.github.com/deepankarb/e69de4373ebd7067e0fc)

Read more :  <sub>https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html</sub>

Answer (score 3):

A bit old, but for future use:

```
Open Android Studio -> app/src/main/res -> Right Click -> Image Asset
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto File->new->ImageAsset.

From their you can create Image Assets for your icon.

After that we will get icon image in *mipmap* different formats like
    hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi.

Now goto AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@mipmap/your_Icon"> ....</application>
```