# What dpi should be set in Photoshop for Android icons?

Tags: icons, android-icons

For designing launcher icons in Android platform, the corresponding guideline says:

> Start with large artboards
>
> Because you will need to create assets for different screen densities,
>   it is best to start your icon designs on large artboards with
>   dimensions that are multiples of the target icon sizes. For example,
>   launcher icons are 96, 72, 48, or 36 pixels wide, depending on screen
>   density. If you initially draw launcher icons on an 864x864 artboard,
>   it will be easier and cleaner to tweak the icons when you scale the
>   artboard down to the target sizes for final asset creation.

But here I can't understand what's meant by 864x864 artboard. Can anyone clarify?

Also, what's the DPI to be set in Photoshop?

In web platform, we normally set 72dpi to design icons of all sizes that ranges from 16x16 to 512x512.

Comment: This has been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10817936/5127735

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

regarding 864x864, 864 is common multiplier for all those sizes. you scale down an image of 864 easily without loss for all resolutions above, 864/9=96 864/12=72...