# error in manifest application tag

Tags: android, xml

Im working on a gps tutorial and I'm getting an error at "@drawable/icon" in the application tag, the error is "no resource found that matches that given name". what am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.ballincoliig.gun.powder.mills.walking.trail"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <activity
                android:name="GPSActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        </application>

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Do you have a file in one of your `drawable` folders named `icon`?

Comment: No i dont, does it matter which drawable folder I put it in?

Comment: @user2083702 what the image file name which is put in drawable folder

Answer (score 1):

Here you can get your answer
[Set icon for android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application)

You will see that there are some folders to update your icon according the resolution of the device you are developing.