# Creating a new Icon Set in Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

In Eclipse there is `File|New|Android Icon Set...`
How do I do the same in the Android Studio?

Comment: That may not be integrated yet. The same capability is available via http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah.. Honestly.. Uh, ok..

Comment: Please be advised that Android Studio is an "early access preview" at the present time. As was explained in the Google I|O presentation, it is missing lots of things.

Comment: In the meantime, while we wait for them to implement it, there are some online tools, as described by the two answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371470/changing-ic-launcher-png-in-android-studio

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The Asset Studio is integrated in Android Studio 0.4.0 and later. To create a new Android icon set, right click on a drawable folder and invoke "New > Image Asset".

Via: [Android Studio 0.4.0 Released](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio040released)

Comment: When I do that in Android Studio 1.0.2 it asks about the 'destination folder'. What properties of the file should influence my choice?

Comment: Android Studio 1.2 creates `Asset Type: Launcher Icons` in the `Output Directories: res/mipmap-...`, instead of `res/drawable-...` (at least when compiling against API 21) which requires referencing them in the `AndroidManifest.xml` as `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` instead of `@drawable/`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935810/mipmap-drawables-for-icons.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't implemented yet in Android Studio; the bug to track it is at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57062 . Others here have noted the links to web-based tools to edit icons. The icon generator in Eclipse ADT is actually ported from the same codebase, as is the icon editor in the new project/activity wizard in Android Studio, so the functionality is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I use an additional module in my Android Studio Projects to let Gradle generate the icon resources. To create icons, I use Inkscape. 
Setup: You have just to add an new module 'icons' to your Android Studio project, taken from [GitHub](https://github.com/chs8691/DemoIconCreator). Then, define once the icons sizes in the my.properties file for mdpi:

```
// All icon heights in dpi for drawable-mdpi
actionbarIcon=32
notificationIcon=30
launcherIcon=40
iconSmall=25
iconMid=35
iconBig=45
```

For every new icon, add a property line to the config file 'icon.properties':

```
// Icon with suffix         | SVG file with suffix      |size property          |module |flavor
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ic_action_export.png        |action_icon_export.svg     |actionbarIcon          |app    |main
```

That's all. Now you can run the Gradle task :icons:generate. This task updates the resource files for every changed icon:

```
app
  - main
    - res
      - drawable-hdpi
        - ic_action_export.png
      - drawable-mdpi
        - ic_action_export.png
      - drawable-xhdpi
        - ic_action_export.png
      - drawable-xxhdpi
        - ic_action_export.png      
      - drawable-xxxhdpi
        - ic_action_export.png
```

See my [blog](http://christian-schulzendorff.blogspot.de/2015/12/including-icon-generation-into-android.html) for a detailed description.