# Rebuild or regenerate 'ic_launcher.png' from images in Android Studio

Tags: icons, android-studio

When one first creates a new project, that dialog lets you point
to some external .PNG file, and then when that dialog completes,
it generates 4 different pixel-sizes of images for use as
a launcher-icon.

My question is:  So, if one already has an existing project
created, is there someplace to tell the Studio to re-generate
4 NEW such files, by just re-pointing it elsewhere, to some
other .PNG?

It occurred to me that I could start a new project and then
manually copy all the other files developed so far, such as
the .JAVA and .XML files, etc, but that seems like a lot of 
work (that I hope won't be necessary).

Answer (score 181):

For `Android Studio 0.4.0` and later, click "`File > New > Image Asset`".

Comment: Ditto in 0.5.1. This should be marked as the answer

Comment: I can't see "New > Image Asset" in the dropdown when i click "File" in Android Studio 0.5.5

Comment: @AmnaAli no problem here with Android 0.5.5. Alternatively, try right clicking on a drawable folder and invoke "New > Image Asset"

Comment: Beware using Asset Studio in Android Studio automatically adds padding, shrinking the resulting image.

Answer (score 52):

No, but you can do this almost as easily.

Go here:

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Build your icons using that page, and then download the zip package. Unzip it into the right directory and it'll overwrite all the drawable-*/ic_launcher.png correctly.

Comment: This will generate legacy icons only though. In Android 9, they will usually look ugly, placed in a white circle.

Answer (score 12):

Just in case anyone else visits this post I thought I'd describe what I did.

1. Right click on res folder > New image asset
2. browser to the icon.  Click next
3. By default the icon goes to src/debug/res- keep this
4. In the project hierarchy, browse to src/debug/res and copy the files from the drawable* 
   directories to the same directories in src/main and src/main
5. copy the src/debug/res/icon_name.png to the src/main and src/release directories

Comment: There is also a dropdown that allows you to choose the destination (debug, main and release).

Answer (score 10):

I can confirm that in Android Studio 1.x (here AS) on Windows also the right sequence is:

- File -> New
- AS opens a list where you must click on Image Asset
- AS opens a dialog where the app\src\main\res Directory Structure is automatically selected (the right choice)
- Clicking on the OK button, AS opens the Asset Studio dialog where you can find all the tools and options we had on the past Eclipse ADT

This can be done absolutely in any moments after creation of the project.

Android Studio warns you that it will overwrite the current ic_launcer, but this is exactly what we expect to do.

Comment: And this also works for Android Studio 2.x except that you will have to right click on the app folder and select File->New from there.

Answer (score 10):

the answers above were confusing to me. Here is what i did:

- File ->new Image Asset
- the first field "Asset type" must be launcher icons. browse to the
  file you want as icon, select it and android studio will show you in
  the same window what it will look like under different resolutions.
- choose a different name for it, click next. Now the **icon set** for
  all those hdpi, xhdpi, mdpi will be in corresponding mipmap folders
- finally, most importantly go to your manifest file and **change**
  "android:icon" to the name of your new icon image.

Comment: Simple and straightforward. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

1. File >In androidStudio Open your application(your project)
2. Go to res folder and then right click on that folder select the new tab in that go to image asset tab you will get asset studio display page .
3. Browse(select) the icon that  you want get as app icon(no need to change the drawble folder) .
4. And then click next tab and finish.
5. your new icon will displayed  in the app.

Comment: this worked for me (make sure you browse to the right path!)

Answer (score 6):

On Android Studio 0.5.8 I managed to change my icon set by right clicking on the 'res' folder and selecting New > Image Asset. This brings you to the icon screen you are presented when creating the application, here after you change the icon it confirms that it will replace all the icons. Confirm and done.

Answer (score 4):

When making an Android app in eclipse, just right-click on the `res` folder, click `New -> Other`, and select `Android Icon Set` under Android.

This allows you to make more icons (or replace any existing ones) easily.

Comment: The question is about Android Studio.

Comment: My bad.
Please refer to LazarusX's answer, as his explains the new way to make icons.

Answer (score 2):

Use the website mentioned in previous posts to create the icons:http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html
Unzip folder and Go into you file explorer on (windows or mac) find AndroidStudioProjects > "app name" > app > src > main (replace the web one here)> res (replace the rest with the one from the unzipped folder the you already downloaded)

*Close android studio so that you can make changes and when android studio is opened again the changes will appear

Answer (score 2):

Put the desired launcher image (.png) in drawable folder.

In AndroidManifest.xml, add

```
android:icon="@drawable/your_img_name"
```

under `application` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an icon using this website https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html.

Download the icon, go to File Explorer - where your projects are saved, the default path is `C:\Users\Your Name\AndroidStudioProjects\Project` Name\app\src\main\res\

and copy the folders you downloaded to the res folder.

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio 0.8 and after
Right click on app folder then    `New > Image Asset`

Browse for best resolution image you have in "Image file" field

hit Next
The rest will be generated

Answer (score 0):

Click "`File > New > Image Asset`"

`Asset Type -> Choose -> Image`

Browse your image

Set the other properties

Press `Next`

You will see the 4 different pixel-sizes of your images for use as a launcher-icon

Press `Finish` !

Comment: I had to go into my manifest and change were it said `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` to use the image i had imported

Answer (score 0):

For Android 3+:

- In the Project window, select the Android view.
- Right-click the res folder and select New > Image Asset.
- If your app supports Android 8.0, create adaptive and legacy launcher icons.
- If your app supports versions no higher than Android 7.1, create a legacy launcher icon only.
- In the Icon Type field, select Launcher Icons (Legacy Only) .
- Select an Asset Type, and then specify the asset in the field underneath.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved by creating an ic_launcher from a PNG image.

1. I converted a PNG image into SVG image by using this website https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg.
2. I used the converted SVG image and converted it into a Vector Asset in Android Studio by, `File > New > Vector Asset`. This converted the SVG image into an XML file.
3. I created the ic_launcher image by creating a new Image Asset in Android Studio by, `File > New > Image Asset`. This created an ic_launcher in a square, round and an Adaptive icon from the XML file.

Note: At the time of writing I faced issues with the SVG image exported from Adobe XD. So I had to use the online converter. Adobe XD does not have xml export feature.