# Why does my launcher icon look different?

Tags: android, android-studio, adaptive-icon

See the image:

[image]

Why does my icon look different to the other icons on the screen? In Android Studio, I set trim to zero and yet it still shows up like this on my phone. I have Nova Launcher installed which makes all my apps have rounded icons, but look at the Google Maps, and Instagram, how do I get my icon to fill the circle?

Comment: have you added `android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"` in manifest file?

Comment: @NileshRathod yes its in there!

Comment: if you want your icon to be like of `maps` just add the icon to the `background` it will cover whole icon

Comment: @AbdulKawee how do I do that?

Comment: well thats for adaptive icons, so simple solution is to change the launcher icons in round, with your custom icon

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371470/changing-ic-launcher-png-in-android-studio

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**WONDERING WHY IT DOES THIS REQUIRES VERY SIMPLE EXPLANATION:**
in new boiler plate code that comes on android studio project generation it makes some extra files in the mip map ! as for the big api based phones have a nature to put a round bracket icon behind every launcher icon of the apps! So All you need to do is very simple if you want to override that! follow the image based foot steps shown below

**HERE IS HOW YOU CAN AD**D A CUSTOM ICON WITHOUT ANY ROUND whit icon behind it!

**STEP ONE!** .

go on your any res folder drawable or mipmap and right click and reach to the option shown in the image:

[image]

**STEP TWO!** .

After clicking on your image asset it will ask to make icons for both old and new phones! but we don't have to select that! ok? see the image for it!

[image]

**STEP THREE!** .

CLICK THE ICON TYPE SPINNER(DROP DOWN) and select mipmap legacy only like shown here

[image]

**STEP FOUR!** .

CUSTOMISE YOUR PICTURE LIKE shown here! by back ground etc how ever you like!

[image]

**STEP FIVE!** .

You will see images being saved only in mipmap folder not in the ic_launcher round folder

[image]

**STEP SIX!** .

You can see the image you created as icon in ic_launcher folder 
but
[image]

**STEP SEVEN!** .

THERE IS a GOTCHA STILL SOME IC_LAUNCHER BUILTIN TEMPLATE PROVIDED files are there you have to delete that folder as shown

:It will cause the alert  that how we are supposed not to do that but its ok! just follow the **step 8** and you will have the icon of your choice no matter what phone you are testing your app on!

[image]
[image]

**STEP EIGHT!** .

GO TO YOUR **MANIFEST FILE** AND DELETE THE HIGHLIGHTED line and you are all set! ^_^

[image]

Comment: Hey man, you did it! Thank you so much for your help and really detailed explanations.  I'm so grateful!

Comment: happy to help ^_^ ! keep asking and tagging on android! @Chud37

Comment: Be careful: this solution won't work if the user's device runs API 26+ and has a launcher shape different than circle!

Comment: @DAA yeah can you please post the link too for the solution! instead of just criticism please before down voting someone's answer give the link of resource solution too! please ! thnx

Comment: You can find two links in my answer, where it is explained how `Adaptive icons` work and how you should generate them. Ignoring them and creating only legacy icons should never be the solution. Always happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

With the release of `Android Oreo` the launcher icons changed a lot.
But with Image Asset Studio (integrated in Android Studio) we can easily generate everything we need (26+ and 25- APIs). [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive) is explained how these new `adaptive icons` work.

In [this article](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#create-adaptive) you can read everything you need to know step by step, but in summary: you need two icons (square and rounded) for 25- APIs, and two layers (background and icon image) for 26+ APIs. Android Studio will generate everything you need if you can provide those elements.

Comment: UP VOTED ^_^ thnx for the answer bless up

Comment: Glad to help! Happy coding!