# Specify drawable size in XML designer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-drawable

I am making an app in Android Studio and I have just started making the splash screen. However, I have been having trouble making the image show up as the right size/quality in the `android:background` property.

Here is the XML code that I am using to display the drawable:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/main_logo"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".Splash">
</RelativeLayout>
```

The drawable is displayed, but it is a small image in the top left corner of the screen.
The original image is 2500 x 2500 pixels at 9999.99 pixels/inch resolution, so it would have no trouble resizing.

How would I specify to use a different size like `xxhdpi` instead of `hdpi` which has been resized, or use the original image and resize it in the center of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually provide separate resources for each folder - mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi ... The system chooses the best to use based on the specific device. If only a single resource is provided for all situations, it will be used by default and you, or your client, will likely *not* like the results.

See [Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more information.

Comment: Android Studio added a resized version for each folder but there are multiple folders that I don't remember putting there (with -v9 and -v11 after the name)

Comment: so there is an image in hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi

Comment: @NattyMan0007, but they aren't displaying correctly? Stupid question -> they aren't the same size though right?

Comment: No they're not all the same size...Android Studio resized them all

Comment: the original image is 25MB and 2500 by 2500 pixels at max resolution but android studio resized it multiple times and put them in folders. If possible could I not use a drawable and use the 25MB image and just resi it?

Comment: You can; you're resizing the ImageView and not the image itself when doing so. You need to get the screen size (width and height) and use those values to compute the right size. @NattyMan0007. Can you point me to some info on auto-generated images; this is the first I've heard of it being possible.

Comment: All i did in Android studio is I went to the res folder and right clicked on it.  Then I went to, New -> Image Asset -> and selected the type as Launcher Icon so it doesn't convert it to another image, then selected the the filepath, renamed it and let Android Studio do the rest

Comment: I just read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049732/creating-a-new-icon-set-in-android-studio) and it turns out that that function is for creating Icon sets for the launcher. I am setting the android:background property and not using an ImageView