# How do I change icon for a Sony Small App?

Tags: android, sdk, icons, manifest, sony

So I've made an app that runs perfectly. The Icon is prepared. Only problem is changing the icon for the small app. Currently it is the standard green robot. I've tried searching Sonys developer pages and checked the docs. Nothing. My current Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.myapp">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sony.smallapp.permission.SMALLAPP" />

<application  android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">

    <uses-library android:name="com.sony.smallapp.framework" />

    <service
            android:name="SmallMyApp"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sony.smallapp.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="com.sony.smallapp.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

Also tried running android:icon="@mipmap/mipicon"

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT*

Leaving the app for a week solved the problem.
Without and input from my side the icon changed magically.

Answer (score 0):

Change here-

```
<application  android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/sony_icon">
```

Comment: Changing the name does not work. I've tried with:
   
`<application  android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/sony_icon">` 
I have also tried with @mipmap/icon, removing it all together, adding android:icon="..." to service and such things.

Comment: Try one thing first remove all robot image from your draw-able folder and then put new icon for sony app..
if there is no robot android icon then from where it will pick it?
well I think some thing wrong in your application you are setting any where else it not in your manifest..

Comment: There is no image in the drawable folder. Only the new icon. It seems to be defaulting to it somewhere else.

Comment: Then god know only what an issue...
:)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your icon drawable in your drawable folder.
You should also check to see if it's the default one (little green Android) in the {x}dpi folders - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application)

Comment: That thread covers the standard app icon. I am trying to set the Sony Small App icon.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the icon for a small app is the same as setting the icon for a regular Android app, so your code should work.

Are you sure that you replaced the icon for all of the different screen resolutions in your res/drawable-*dpi folders?

Are you testing on the emulator or actual HW?  If HW, what device are you trying this on?