# choose the correct dpi folder to put 32px x 32px and 36px x 36px in android

Tags: android, icons

I want to put the icon on drawable folder. I see on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application) , I can put the icon that have 36px x 36px in drawable-ldpi. But, I feel confused to put the icon for 32px x 32px. Where I should put that icon?

Answer (score 0):

From the [developer-document](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html):

> Note: Android also supports low-density (LDPI) screens, but you normally don't need to create custom assets at this size because Android effectively down-scales your HDPI assets by 1/2 to match the expected size.

I suggest you to enlarge 32 px icon to 36px and then either keep it in ldpi folder or keep 72x72 resolution images in hdpi folder.

Comment: yes, you're correct. but how about 32x32? where I should put it?

Answer (score 0):

Enlarge 32 px icon to 36px and then either keep it in ldpi folder or keep 72x72 resolution images in hdpi folder as @illegal-argument suggested below is the snapshot of project explorer, as you can see you can find ldpi and hpdi inside res folder

[image]