# How to update/make a live icon in Android app?

Tags: android, android-icons

I am new to android app development. (please be elaborate)

---

I want to make a live icon for my weather app  which shows current temperature on the icon, just like MIUI calender app which shows date on its icon.

I browsed all over the internet but could not find a way to make a live icon. Even a link to a tutorial would be helpful.

---

**edit:**

- I don't want to make a widget.
- I don't want to change an icon of already published app, by update I meant the app be able to update the icon on the basis of the data it receives.

I want the icon to be dynamic instead of static.

Comment: This is also done by the clock icon (at least as of Android Phone)

Comment: Did you find anything in the last 3 years?

Answer (score -1):

## Changing an application icon - Android

1. Change your application icon. For help follow the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10817936/3819836
2. Change +1 to your version code in manifest file So that users can get application updates for the version we are working for. For more help follow: [Versioning Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)
3. Sign APK with an existing keystore (with which you published app to play store). For more help follow: [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)
4. Upload this APK to the play store. Users will get an update for your application and after installing they'll have a changed icon as we've worked for.

Comment: i haven't published the app yet and i want the application to be dynamic not static so once the weather app gets the data it updates the icon simultaneously. just like calender apps which show the date on the icon. i don't want to change the icon of already published app

Comment: As I understand, you want to load some icons depending on your data fetched (temprature value) from your server or some other API source?

Comment: exactly... i know that the icon has to be static image that's why my only option is to modify the icon image or change its source completely

Comment: Place these icons in you drawable resources. On getting your fetched data, by making some decisional implementation, you should change your image/icon from your drawable resources programmatically. Are you using widgets for your application?

Comment: how do i do that? i mean i can't modify the manifest during runtime, right?

Comment: I understand what you want to say actually, sorry but I don't know about, I also did an effort for you but it was not working :(

Comment: thankyou for trying, i will be researching and when i find a way i will post it here as an answer :)

Comment: You're most welcome, and that'll be very helpful :)

Answer (score -2):

In android OS can't provide us way to create a live launcher icon, for example facebook status counter, if you want to use you have to create your own logic, by default android didn't provide

Comment: oh... how can i change the source of icon? i think then i may be able to create a logic

Comment: Android provide widget support for continues/live visualization of your data, that's why its recommend to use widget rather than live launcher icon, but if still you want to do, go and create your custom logic and waste your time

Comment: i don't want to make a widget because many of us don't like to use one.. the use ram and space on homescreen... i want the app to be useful on low end devices too, i just want to learn how to make the icon dynamic weather or not i use it in the future.

Answer (score -2):

I think, when you're saying 'live icon', you're actually referring to Android Widgets. Take a look at the official documentation for more info - http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html .

Comment: sorry for not being clear...but i want the app icon in the app drawer to be able to show the current temperature. so one does not have to open the app just to know the temperature.