# How to change Android App Icon on AndroidStudio (IntellJ based)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile, intellij-idea

I have been having a tough time trying to figure out how to change Android icon on the new Android Studio (based on idea intelliJ). I have migrated from Eclipse to this recently, and I am new to this IDE.

My question is very simple, **is there a way to upload a PNG - and Android automatically creates images in the respective `/mipmap-*` folders, with respective resolution.**

In Eclipse there was an option to upload an image, and it would automatically update those into the repective folders by adjusting the icon resolution. Eclipse also had options like making the app icon circular/square with some basic shadow effects.

If there are any more details needed, I would be happy to edit this question to make it more clear.

Comment: You may need to create image and then name it as ic_launcher.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set icon for Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on your app -> new -> Image asset

Comment: This is a good start - DO i still need to add icon's to the respective folder? doesn't androidstudio auto-add?

Comment: No. Remove the current icon. Right click on app -> new -> Image asset . Name it (ic_laucher) and Android Studio will add icon to the respective folder for you . Let's take a try !

Comment: thanks for your help. This helped me a lot. I am selecting your answer as the right answer. Thanks!