# Kivy properly set own icon

Tags: android, python, icons, kivy

I have my own icon (KO.png: 512x512 (also got in sizes 48, 72, 96, 144 and 192)) in the same folder as my main.py. I want to set it as a **launcher icon** (1), in **ActionPrevious** (2) and **loading icon** (3).

1) The first step is to put in main.py:

```
def build(self):
    self.icon = 'KO.png'
```

At some point this worked, but can't get it to work again?

---

2) I also have an ActionBar with ActionPrevious. I want to set my own logo here. So I have in the appname.kv:

```
ActionPrevious:
    app_icon: app.icon if app.icon else ''
```

This works in Linux, but **not** in Android. In Android I still have the Kivy logo. **Also** if I use the 512x512 icon, it is blurry on Linux. If I use the 92x92, it looks fine.

*Edit:* ActionPrevious does work, the app just didn't properly build because of the incorrect path in buildozer.spec (see 3)

---

3) Also I want the loader icon to be my own logo, so I have the following code in buildozer.spec:

```
icon.filename = KO.png
presplash.filename = KO.png
```

There was before '%(source.dir)s/', but this doesn't work either:

```
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/KO.png
presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/KO.png
```

Edit: However both these paths result in buildozer **not building** the .apk, what is the correct path?

---

**Question**

- How do I properly set my own icon in Kivy as launcher, loading screen and in ActionPrevious (AP is working, see *Edit* under 2) ), what is the correct icon.filename path?
- How can I get a sharp icon in my ActionPrevious with a 512x512 icon? (ActionItem doc: mipmap is a BooleanProperty and defaults to True.)
- How can a single 512x512 icon work out on all devices with Kivy, when normally they recommend multiple sizes?: [Set icon for android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application?rq=1). Doesn't re-scaling has its limits when making it very small?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O wow... I was stuck on this so long because buildozer doesn't support in-line comments... I had it like this in my buildozer.spec:

```
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/ko.png # %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png
```

This is what solved it:

```
# %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/ko.png
```