# Android change app icon

Tags: android, manifest

I can't really figure out how to change the app's icon that appears when you install the app, the one on the screen that you have to click.

What i did:

- I created a new icon --> new > Image asset (mipmap)
- I deleted ic_launcher (the default one)
- I named the new asset like the old icon (ic_launcher)
- Rebuild
- Clean project
- Invalidate cache and restart
- Installed app

nothing. I still have my app with the annoying default mipmap ic_launcher icon.

I don't really know what to do more than this..

Can anyone help me?

EDIT:
Sorry, I forgot the manifest.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true" >
...
...
</application>
```

Comment: Hey, I am stuck with the same problem. Can you please provide the solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411981/app-icon-not-being-set-it-is-always-showing-default-green-android-icon

Comment: @suku sorry, i forgot doing it. I posted below hoe I solved my problem, hope it helps!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set icon for Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Suke pointed I forgot posting the solution for this question. Sorry all.

After a lot of managements the solution was easy and it was the one google's one.

[this link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html) is where you can create all images for android project.

Go there and:

- insert your image and select all features
- download it
- replace all image formats (xxhdpi, hdpi, ...) in your drawable-xxhdpi, drawable xhdpi,... and mipmap-xxhdpi, mipmap-xhdpi,... folders.
- in manifest set the `android:icon = "@drawable/myicon"`

this is how I did it

hope it helps

Comment: I deleted everything about ```android:icon``` then created from scratch and it worked

Answer (score 2):

use this side to create icon by uploading the image (use image button)

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=607d8b%2C0&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&backColor=ffffff%2C100&effects=none

and then download and save this in drawable folder of your app and then use

```
 <application
      android:icon="@drawable/myIcon" >
 </application>
```

in manifests file.

Comment: i'm trying, sorry for late reply but i was busy those days

Comment: Ok, with a little adjust it worked: the zip I downloaded, was a res folder with mipmap(for each size) folders inside. i had to rename all mipmap folders into drawable folders and now it works. Do you know why if I refer to a mipmap image the icon is not changing but if i point to a Drawable icon yes?

Comment: yes i know because your icon file are place in the folder of drawable and if you want to show with mipmap folder then you have to do.
first place the file ic_launncher(myIcon) in the folder of mipmap and the replace the code in manifests file with this

        <application
      android:icon="@mipmap/myIcon" >
      </application>

you have to only replace the folder name after @ sign in mainfests file

Comment: replace your app res folder with res folder from your zip then your old code of mipmap will work. For more detail check my new answer.

Answer (score 2):

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=607d8b%2C0&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&backColor=ffffff%2C100&effects=none

After generating your icon and downloading the zip file by using the side given above then extract the res folder from zip file and overwrite res folder(by pasting at location e.g. C:\MyApplicaton\app\src\main) of your app with this res folder then your code

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

will work.
Note: by overwriting res folder it only add or overwrite the mipmap folders and old folder will remain as it was.

OR

you have to replace the ic_launcher icon in all mipmap folder with new ic_launcher according to the icon size with the help of the side given above.

then it will work

folder name like

mipmap-hdpi

mipmap-mdpi

mipmap-xhdpi

mipmap-xxhdpi

Then your code as given below will work

```
   <application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true" >
 ...
 ...
 </application>
```

Comment: I had no reason to use the tool above, as Android Studio itself will let you pick images (unless you want something really custom).  The important part of this answer is the format- modern versions use mipmap instead of the original -drawable.  Be very careful that it is in the opening Activity tag in the manifest.  It will allow you to paste it outside of this, but it will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You set your application icon under the `<application>` tag in your manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/myIcon" >
</application>
```

Then just make sure you have a file (such as `myIcon.png`) within your resources folder (hdpi, xhdpi, etc)

Comment: Have you tried using a unique name? Not sure if using the `ic_launcher` name is giving you troubles (reserved words, maybe?)

Comment: ic_launcher is just the default name. I would double check to make sure that the same icon is being used at all densities.

Comment: sorry for late reply but i was busy those days, my icons have all the same name, i checked.. I created them with "Image asset" for meing sure of it and I checked :(

Answer (score 1):

first paste icon.png file in drawable folder and modify your code as below

```
    <application
          android:allowBackup="true"
          android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:supportsRtl="true" >

    </application>
```

Comment: sorry for late reply but i was busy those days, I'm trying it :)

Answer (score 1):

In the Manifest add  android:icon="@drawable/Icon" in the

`<application
    android:icon="@drawable/Icon" >
</application>`

make sure that the icon is present in the folder

Answer (score 1):

If you still see default android icon, it's simple to fix it...
You can use this tools to generate an all-sizes icon. https://appicon.co/
Unzip the mipmap resized file in app res folder.
Then in /mipmap-anydpi-v26/ folder, delete both XML files.

Now in the manifest, in the `<application>` tag, set your icon for both `android:icon` & `android:roundIcon`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, I created an icon with [this link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher). In my case, I had to adjust both the following parameters to the icon name I added in res.

```
<application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did not uninstall the App with the old icon and upgraded over it, there is a chance it may display the old icon due to cache. Force stopping the App may help.

Comment: thanks for replying. I tryed it, i unistalled app and reinstalled but didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to update the `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` with the new value, this is valid for newer versions of android.