# App icon not being set, it is always showing default green android icon

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, android-icons

I have followed the following steps as suggested by tutorials and other stack overflow questions:

1. android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" in the manifest where the app icon is named ic_launcher and all the mipmaps have been appropriately replaced on basis of resolution
2. replaced all mipmap images with the the images generated from [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)
3. I have selected the appropriate files in the image asset by right clicking on res.
4. I have uninstalled the old app. Rebuilt the app the ans then run
5. I have invalidated cache and restarted Android Studio too
6. Restarted the mobile
7. Added a 512 * 512 pixel image in image asset too.

The problem I suspect is that when I launch the image asset, the default is on clipart and not on image. So everytime the app is run it may be picking up the default clipart icon.

I have also kept the app icon in the toolbar. This changes sometimes. If the app is run again it changes back to the default green android icon.

I have the new android studio 2.1. So is there some problem with it in this regards?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the manifest:

```
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

In the drawable folder, I added my logo named ic_launcher having size 192*192 pixels.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37414062/5512020) set me on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

Rename icon file to any other name in all folders & change it in menifest.xml as well.

If it was **ic_launcher**, change it to any other name say **app_icon** in folders & menifest.xml as well.

Uninstall app & install it again.

Hope will help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed in manifest file?

android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" to

android:icon="@mipmap/your_app_logo_name"

Comment: I have kept app_logo_name to ic_launcher

Comment: Have you changed in all mipmaps?