# Android app icon is default icon on homescreen

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I cannot update the icon on the homescreen. It is the green robot default android icon. How can I change this to the icon?

I have added icons in the `app > src > res` folder for different resolutions.

I am uploaing my app using the play console. Any ideas?

My manifest states:

```
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

The name matches the image in the assets folders.

Here is a link to my repo:

https://bitbucket.org/matthisco/ejected-calendar/src/master/android/app/src/main/

Comment: change images in mipmap folder

Comment: I have they're all there

Comment: check your manifest file under application tag find `android:icon` change its value to your new icon

Comment: Its the same name, ic_launcher.png

Comment: in this case recheck all images.. in all folder there might be on left out

Comment: Still not working, I have added a link to my repo

Comment: @Bomber I can not access your repo. Is it public? Or add me to it so I can take a look

Comment: @Bomber Did you ever come to a solution? I'm experiencing the same issue too..

Comment: Nevermind, I don't know why this page was one of the few results from Google. Google is broken. Anyways, if anyone is landing here. Here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876329/android-change-app-icon/37414062#37414062

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set icon for Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application)

Answer (score 2):

Change project to android 
than go to res>mipmap>paste your icon there (iconName.png)
replace

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" in manifest
```

to

```
android:icon="@mipmap/iconName"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update the homescreen icon as follows:

In **AndroidManifest.xml** under **application** tag

```
 <application
  android:icon="@mipmap/yourdesiredIcon"/> // replace ic_launcher to desired icon
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto `app > src > main > res`

rename your icon to `ic_launcher.png` and paste it to all mipmap folders

Answer (score 0):

The correct folder where the Android icon must be placed is `res->mipmap-xxxx` where `xxxx` signals the screen resolution.

Also check that your manifiest is using it. Open the manifest and in the **application** tag you should have something like this:

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Also verify you icon is named `ic_launcher`.

As you can see that entry in the manifest says *"go look for the icon in the mipmap folder, use the one named ic_launcher"*

Comment: does it need the `.png` ?

Comment: Yes, they are .png files. Also the filename must be all lowercase

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, but I realized that in the Android Manifest

```
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

were pointing to the same images, which were square. The phone I was testing on had a round icon, and so the default android image was displaying, I presume because the format was incorrect.
When I then tested on a phone with a square image, the images were displaying correctly.