# How to add icons to React Native app

Tags: icons, react-native

I am making a React Native app. I would like to customize the app icon (meaning the icon that you click on to start the app). I have Googled this, but I keep finding different types of icons that refer to different things. How do I add these types of icons to the app?

Comment: Is this for iOS, Android or both?

Comment: now for ios but eventually for both

Comment: See this answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11845815/5576491

Answer (score 533, accepted):

### iOS Icons

- Set `AppIcon` in `Images.xcassets`.
- Add 9 different size icons:

  - `29pt`
  - `29pt*2`
  - `29pt*3`
  - `40pt*2`
  - `40pt*3`
  - `57pt`
  - `57pt*2`
  - `60pt*2`
  - `60pt*3`.

`Images.xcassets` will look like this:

[image]

### Android Icons

- Put `ic_launcher.png` in folders `[ProjectDirectory]/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-*/`.

  - 72*72 `ic_launcher.png` in `mipmap-hdpi`.
  - 48*48 `ic_launcher.png` in `mipmap-mdpi`.
  - 96*96 `ic_launcher.png` in `mipmap-xhdpi`.
  - 144*144 `ic_launcher.png` in `mipmap-xxhdpi`.
  - 192*192 `ic_launcher.png` in `mipmap-xxxhdpi`.

### Update 2019 Android

The latest versions of react native also supports round icon. For this particular case, you have two choices:

**A. Add round icons:**
In each mipmap folder, add additionally to the `ic_launcher.png` file also a round version called `ic_launcher_round.png` with the same size.

**B. Remove round icons:**
Inside `yourProjectFolder/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` remove the line `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"`and save it.

Otherwhise the build throws an error.

Comment: Nice. I wonder if this could be improved by using an image from the app assets, probably it would need to be `require()`ed somewhere.

Comment: @adam-katz, this really should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Exist any way for make for both directly in react-native?

Comment: Just to update this great answer.  You now also need 83.5pt*2 for the iPadPro on iOS.

Comment: I wrote a generator to automatically generate icons for your react native app from a single icon file :) Hope it can help others! (See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329715/how-to-add-icons-to-react-native-app/40534324#40534324))

Comment: Where is this in the react native documentation?

Comment: If you want to one day use vectors instead of this maniacal resizing check out [Die, PNG! Die!](https://medium.com/@webalys/die-png-die-how-to-use-vector-icons-in-your-apps-d884c9c63e93)

Comment: For android, you can use this tool: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#
(I'm not affiliated with that tool)

Comment: The point B, removing round icon line from manifest is not needed in my case, the build is not throwing any error.

Comment: What does the 3 in "29pt*3" mean?

Comment: I have read this answer, and only after some time read Almouro's answer below. I wish I started with Almouro's answer.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Then, I used the package referenced in Almouro's answer below. Works great,

Answer (score 351):

I wrote a generator to **automatically generate icons** for your react native app from a single icon file. It generates your assets and it also adds them correctly to your ios and android project:

## Update (04/09/2019)

We revamped our generator to be up to date with the ecosystem standards. You can now use [@bam.tech/react-native-make](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-make).

You can **install it** using: `yarn add @bam.tech/react-native-make` in the react-native project

To **use it** `react-native set-icon --path <path_to_png> --background <icon_background_color> --platform <android|ios>`

And... that's it! Hope it can be useful for others :)

**Recommendations:**

- 1024x1024 base image
- No transparent background for iOS
- An icon which follows [adaptive icons guidelines](https://medium.com/google-design/designing-adaptive-icons-515af294c783) for Android

Here are **some improvements** over the previous tool:

- No Yeoman dependency, it is now a react-native-cli plugin
- No Image Magick dependency
- Creates Adaptive icons for Android
- Adds missing icons sizes for iOS

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You save me huge amount of time! As app developers we really don't care how many icons iOS and Android need, for 9 icons and 4 icons all have same content, who cares? For retina or not retina, for big or small screen, who cares? Just give me the exactly clear and same icons, that's it! Thank you and I would like to try your other tools. :)

Comment: I found the problem: When installing image-magick, make sure to install legacy tools so the `convert` command will exist.

Comment: @RickLove I also had this issue after installing imagemagick with `yarn -g add imagemagick`. I then installed it using `homebrew` instead (`brew install imagemagick`) which installed everything necessary and worked.

Comment: @Denialos I don't need donations haha, thanks for asking :) But you're mostly welcome to contribute here: https://github.com/bamlab/generator-rn-toolbox

Comment: @Almouro Is it possible to get it to work without Ruby? I find the pre-requisites too much

Comment: @PolaEdward no need for Ruby :) All the requirements are here: https://github.com/bamlab/generator-rn-toolbox/blob/master/generators/assets/README.md#requirements

Comment: @Almouro Aha, I checked the requirements on the main Repo readme, and I thought it applies to everything inside

Comment: This eventually worked great but it looks like Apple App Store requirements may have changed to require additional icon sizes of 120, 76, 167, 152 which I manually added into /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-rn-toolbox/generators/assets/imageGenerator.js in `const iosIconSizes...`

Comment: Superb! Just rembember that on mac it'll be necessary to install imagemagick `https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick`. Use brew.

Comment: is this for exported final apps only? or works also on development with expo app?

Comment: I was facing issue on Windows after following all the necessary steps required eventually had to install the library

- Must select the *"Install legacy utilities (e.g. convert)* on 'Select Additional Tasks

Link: '[http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

Comment: it helped a lot, but is there anyway to add round icons too? these library just adds normal icons for android. thank you again

Comment: Don't you need to modify `app.json`? If so, how should it look like?

Comment: I was trying this with `npx`, the exact command I run is: `npx  @bam.tech/react-native-make &&  react-native set-icon --path ../logo.jpg `, but it failed with error `command not found: react-native-make`. How can I try this with `npx`?

Comment: after to used this library unistall that

Answer (score 35):

I would use a service to scale the icon correctly. http://makeappicon.com/ seems good. Use a image on the larger size as scaling up a smaller image can lead to the larger icons being pixelated. That site will give you sizes for both iOS and Android.

From there its just a matter of setting the icon like you would a regular native app.

https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev10510b1f7

[Set icon for Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application)

Comment: Apple link is broken, @rmevans9. :(

Comment: Note this service collects information about you - such as app name, market category of the app, etc - and prevents image download unless an email address is provided.

Comment: I have read this answer, and only after some time read Almouro's answer below. I wish I started with Almouro's answer.

Answer (score 28):

I was able to add an app icon to my react-native android project by following [this guy's advice](http://harrymoreno.com/2016/01/21/add-launcher-icon-to-react-native-android-app.html) and using [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html)

Here it is, transcribed in case the link goes dead:

**How to upload an Application Icon in React-Native Android**

1) Upload your image to [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html).
 Pick whatever effects you’d like to apply. The tool generates a zip file for you. Click Download .Zip.

2) Unzip the file on your machine. Then drag over the images you want to your `/android/app/src/main/res/` folder. Make sure to put each image in the right subfolder `mipmap-{hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi}.`

[image: android/app/src/main/res]

3) Do not (as I originally did) naively drag and drop the whole folder over your res folder. As you may be removing your `/res/values/{strings,styles}.xml` files altogether.

Answer (score 15):

Android Studio has a very handy icon asset wizard called Image Asset Studio [(user guide here)](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio). It's quite self explainatory, and has a few handy effects and it's built right in:

[image]

Screenshot from Android Studio 4.1.3 on Windows 10
[image]

Comment: Do you build your rect-native projects in Android Studio?

Comment: No, but i regularly have to open it for some reason or another. Same with XCode - eventually you need to cross over to the other side. This is the method I use to generate high quality icon sets in seconds, very suprised it has had such a strong response. Hell - I even own my own open source project to generate icons for mobile apps and I still prefer this method. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-media-generator

Comment: This was awesome - it also prettified the icons, which I found super helpful (like this answer!).

Comment: Brilliant! Nice one!

Comment: I've Android Studio 4.1 on MacOS, and I don't see the option to open Image Assets with right click over that folder, neither over others.

Comment: Hey @SebastianDiaz you need to wait for gradle to finish doing its thing before it shows up, usually there is notice in the bottom bar on the right

Comment: I needed to install "node" with sudo to use this. Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63073599/10247962

Answer (score 13):

Someone made a very easy to use tool just for this task: https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-icon

> This simple tool allows you to create a single icon in your react-native project, then create icons of all required sizes from it. It currently works for iOS and Android.

I've used it. Made a 512x512 png and then ran that tool and boom, done. Super easy.

Comment: PS: react-native-icon is marked as deprecated and has been renamed to app-icon; https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-icon

Comment: I get trouble to install react-native-make which is mentioned in Almouro's answer. Then I find this app-icon can be installed correctly and it's simple and works well.

Answer (score 8):

You'll need different sized icons for iOS and Android, like Rockvic said. In addition, I recommend this site for generating different sized icons if anybody is interested. You don't need to download anything and it works perfectly.

https://resizeappicon.com/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 8):

**This is helpful for people struggling to find better site to generate icons and splashscreen**

- [Make App Icon](https://makeappicon.com/) (useful for both android and ios)
- [APE tools](https://apetools.webprofusion.com/app/#/tools/imagegorilla) (useful for both android and ios)
- [Icon set creator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icon-set-creator/id939343785?mt=12) (useful for ios only)
- [Andoid Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=image&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba%2896%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200%29&backColor=rgb%28255%2C%20255%2C%20255%29&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher)(useful for android only + recommended*)

Answer (score 7):

## Update 2022

Since the Almouro's Answer is no longer maintained

### Android and iOS icon

You can now generate icons with one command both for iOS and Android with rounded icon:

```
npx icon-set-creator create ./path/to/icon.png
```

> I highly recommend using an icon with a size of at least 1024x1024 pixels

### Adaptive Android icon

```
npx icon-set-creator create -b <background> -f <foreground> -A
```

**background** - The color (E.g. "#ffffff") or image asset (E.g. "assets/images/christmas-background.png")

**foreground** -  The image asset (E.g. "assets/images/christmas-foreground.png")

Comment: Thank you, I get " ERROR  No image path was specified for android" for the adaptive android icon, do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Didn't work for me, after the command the app still uses old icon.

Answer (score 6):

**Steps Android App icons:**
Go to this website **https://appicon.co/**

1. Add image their and generate icons, it should be downloaded
2. Unzip the folder
3. Inside their copy all the folders in AppIcons/android/ (i.e. Folder
   names: mipmap-xxxhdpi,mipmap-xxhdpi,mipmap-xhdpi,mipmap-hdpi,mipmap-mdpi)
4. paste above copied folders into {rootFolder}/android/app/src/main/res/
   and replace existing ones
5. Remove this line from AndroidManifest.xml
   (android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round")

Icons are successfully added

**Change IOS App icons:**
Go to this website **https://appicon.co/**

1. Add image their and generate icons, it should be downloaded
2. Unzip the folder
3. Inside their copy all the folders in AppIcons/Assets.xcassets/ (i.e.
   AppIcon.appiconset folder)
4. paste the AppIcon.appiconset folder into
   {rootFolder}/ios/{projectname}/Images.xcassets/ and replace existing one

Icons are successfully added

Answer (score 2):

If you're using expo just place an 1024 x 1024 png file in your project and 
add an icon property to your app.json i.e. "icon": "./src/assets/icon.png"

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/app-icons

Answer (score 2):

For setting the **App launch icon** for **Android Devices** in a **React-Native** project:

- Take a high resolution image of your logo and place it inside your project directory. Preferably in [Project-DIR]/android/app/src/main/res/
- Open Android Studio and run your React-native project.
- In Android Studio's Project window, select the [Android view](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects#ProjectFiles)
- Right-click the res folder and select New > Image Asset
- A "Configure Image Asset" window will open; Locate your high resolution image and place set it as your "Foreground layer".
- Set your "Background Layer" if applicable
- Click "Next" and continue to finish.
- Run your application again to see the new app launch icon.

Official documentation can be found here: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio

Answer (score 1):

Use this library to make your work easier.
It will automate your Icon generation process

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bam.tech/react-native-make

Answer (score -1):

I personally use this link to generate my desired icons https://appicon.co/

And for importing inside the application.

> For IOS Setup

Click on your project from Xcode ==>

then on the left side you will see your   click on that ==>

Now you will see subfile name  Images.xcassets click on that ==>

you icons size will be displayed on the right hand window ==>

simply drag and drop the icons which we have generated from https://appicon.co/  ==>

and your IOS ICON SETUP IS DONE.

> Moving to Android

We will go to Android ==> app ==> src ==> main ==> res

Here you will various folders named mipmap-hdpi till xxxhdpi ==>

Drag the icons from the specific folder to your project specific folder.
Happy coding!

Comment: I don't understand your english

Answer (score -1):

To import icons on React Native if you want the icons without having the pictures, then react-native-vector-icons would be the best one. You can use it if you don't want to download the icons and use it in your project.

Answer (score -4):

I would like to suggest to use react-native-vector-icons to import icons to your project. As you use vector icons, you don't need to worry much on icon scaling side. While using the package you are able to use all popular icon set such as fontawesome, ionicons etc..

Besides these iconsets you can also bring your own icons too to your react-native project by packing your icons as a ttf file and you can import that ttf directly to both android and ios project. You can utilise the same react-native-vector-icons library to manage those icons

Here is a detailed procedure to setup custom icons

https://medium.com/bam-tech/add-custom-icons-to-your-react-native-application-f039c244386c

Answer (score -10):

You can import react-native-elements and use the font-awesome icons to your react native app

Install

```
npm install --save react-native-elements
```

then import that where you want to use icons

```
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'
```

Use it like

```
render() {
   return(
    <Icon
      reverse
      name='ios-american-football'
      type='ionicon'
      color='#517fa4'
    />
 );
}
```

Comment: How can we add icons for Android, because we specify the name as `ios-american-football` ? or we can replace ios by android in this syntax?

Comment: This doesn't address the original question.

Comment: The post is about launcher icon and has nothing to do with react-native-elements. The library is just for in-app icons.

Comment: Question is about app icon - it is icon user can see on the launch screen of the devaice