# Change App Name In React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to figure out how to change a ReactNative app name.
The installed APK on my device is simply "App", with the Android icon.
How can I change this?

I've tried changing package.json and re-running react-native upgrade but it didn't update AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 246, accepted):

The generator does not override the `strings.xml` file located in `android/app/src/main/res/values/`, so you have to change the `app_name` variable manually

Comment: Also make sure that the getMainComponentName() in your MainActivity returns your react native app name. i.e. name in app.json

Comment: what about IOS ?

Comment: react-native-rename is apparently [unmaintained and unuseable at this point.](https://github.com/junedomingo/react-native-rename/issues/76)

Comment: What about iOS ?

Comment: to change react-native IOS App display name you can change 'Bundle display name' property from info.plist

Comment: Thanks @JohnMuraguri.  That was needed.  The MainActivity.java file is found in android\app\src\main\java\com\[your folder name\

Answer (score 119):

**For Android**

Modify **displayName** in **app.json** file

Modify **app_name** in **android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml**

then Run these commands one by one

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
react-native run-android
```

**For iOS**

Modify **Display Name** in Project target (General Tab)

Select your application project as Host Application in Project target for testing  (General Tab)[image]

Comment: its not showing my `display name` in Host Application drop down

Comment: `displayName` is corresponding to key `name` in `app.json`

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/68641035/9383288, you need to put `&#x2007;` instead of spaces in the `Info.plist` file.

Answer (score 72):

Try [react-native-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename) this npm package will ease the process

```
This package assumes that you created your react-native project 
using react-native init.
```

**Note:** This package does not attempt to properly rename build artifacts such as ios/build or Cocoa Pod installation targets. After renaming your project you should clean, build, and reinstall third party dependencies to get it running properly with the new name.

```
// in project directory

   npx react-native-rename <newName>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16498360)

Comment: issue addressed

Comment: The command should be `react-native-rename`. I couldn't edit because edits have to be > 6 characters :(

Comment: Rename command says-"Directory should be created using react-native init"!

Comment: Adding anything globally with `yarn` is a poor practice. I would advise against it. As noted in their doc "For the vast majority of packages it is considered a bad practice to have global dependencies because they are implicit."

Comment: @MikeS. this is not a bad practice since it is NOT a project dependency but a tool, and having them as project dependencies is indeed a bad practice. Is like CRNA, you should have it as a global tool

Comment: i have some issue with a package name !
i'm using firebase in my app and say 
> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.myapp'

Comment: WARNING: Do not use this library. it will ruine your project. Never use this.

Comment: This package is DOPE. Saved my bacon

Comment: DO NOT USE. As of this writing, this package is deprecated / unmaintained and will make your project unusable.

Comment: It is not a project dependency and worked fine for me anyway. I will update my feedback in case it causes any issue

Comment: @SQueryL did it caused any problem yet? It's working for me.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an issue with Persian names or it ignores spaces in the name in general. Any way, it did not handle sth like "اسم اپ" very well.

Comment: This package works wonders. Note that if you have already manually renamed certain parts of your project before running the `react-native-rename` command, it will not work and you'll have to revert those changes

Comment: Gosh an npm package just to rename an app name?

Answer (score 61):

**First of all:**
Open `app.json` file in your react-native project directory. And, just replace `displayName` json property's value in this file. e.g.:

```
{
    "name": "SomethingSomething",
    "displayName": "My New App Name"
}
```

**For Android app:**
Open `strings.xml` file, replace the `<string name="app_name">` tag's value to your new app name. e.g.:

```
<string name="app_name">My New App Name</string>
```

**For iOS:**
Open `info.plist`, replace the value after `<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>` to your app name. e.g.:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>My New App Name</string>
```

Uninstall your previous app installed on your device. Use **npm install** in project main directory, in ios folder directory run **pod install** commands. Now, simply install app in your device.

Comment: If i want to change the Bundle Identifier?

Comment: @OliverD For Android, change application ID in android/app/build.gradle file and for iOS, change the Bundle Identifier in iOS project. Don't forget to re-configure your third-party accounts in case of google sign in, facebook sign in etc.

Comment: If you want everything clean you need also to open xcode and rename your app from there.

Comment: This fixes the app name for iOS, thanks! But the Splash Screen still has the old app name. How do I update the app name on the Splash Screen?

Answer (score 45):

**UPDATE 2021**
React native version: **0.64.0**

**Android** 
Find and open following files and change as required. 
`\android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml`

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My App</string>
</resources>
```

`app.json`

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "displayName": "My App"
}
```

**iOS** 
Find and open the `\ios\YourAppName\Info.plist` and change as required.
**NOTE:** if your name has spaces use `&#x2007;` instead of spaces.

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>My&#x2007;App</string>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: You're a life-saver! It took a long time to find the trick with the spaces!

Answer (score 36):

The way I did this for android (hacky, but it works) is just changed the string `app_name` field in

`android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`

It will change the name of your installed android app to whatever you put as the value.

Comment: I tried this method, but it didnt solve my problem. When app run in my mobile its says with an error "Application <prev appname> has not been registered"

Comment: Tried  @KlaasNotFound method. Successfully got new build uprunning

Comment: I got same problem like @NIKHILCM with react-native 0.56

Answer (score 17):

I find that, **if you want to change both the app name *and* the package name** (i.e. rename the entire app), the following steps are necessary:

- Make sure you don't have anything precious (non-generated, manually copied resources) in the `android/` and `ios/` subfolders.
- Delete both the `android/` and `ios/` folder.
- Change the `"name"` entry in your `package.json` to the new name.
- Change the app name in both your `index.android.js` and `index.ios.js`:
  `AppRegistry.registerComponent('NewAppName', () => App);`
- Run `react-native upgrade` to re-generate the platform subfolders.
- If you have linked resources (like custom fonts etc.) run `react-native link`.
- If you have other generated resources (like app icons) run the scripts to generate them (e.g. [`yo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40534324/6424399)).
- Finally, uninstall the old app on each device and run the new one.

Comment: Just a note: I think step #1 should be `create a repo test branch first`.

Comment: As of today, there's a new npm package that alleges to minimize these issues, `react-native-git-upgrade`. But I can't get it to run using `yarn`. My project doesn't use `npm`, nor do I want to install it globally. So, trying to figure out my options. So far, `react-native-git-upgrade` fails from CLI

Comment: thanks a lot for you steps I followed some and it worked

Comment: Also have to do a debug keystore https://stackoverflow.com/a/57438549/5900793

Comment: `react-native upgrade` does not generate platform subfolders anymore.

Comment: This answer should no longer be valid since `react-native upgrade` does not create the subfolders anymore. I just followed these steps and now I'm left without these folders.

Answer (score 13):

If you are asking only for Android here is solution

Modify **`displayName`** in **`/app.json`** file

Modify **`app_name`** in **`android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`**

then 
Run these commands one by one

```
cd android
gradlew clean
cd ..
react-native run-android
```

Comment: how come i cant run react-native eject and it says i `name` must be defined in the `app.json` but i have it?

Comment: this will cause error: Invariant vilation: xxxAPP has not been registered. ( xxxAPP was the older app name)

Comment: If youre running on windows gradlew should be run using ./gradlew

Comment: @tesshsu Before install the APP with the new name, you should uninstall the previous APP.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't have any thing precious in your android folder, you can delete the folder then run `react-native upgrade` then `react-native android`. These will recreate AndroidManifest.xml along with necessary files and folders. (Tried on 0.18 in Windows 10)

Comment: Works on macOS Sierra as well.

Answer (score 8):

for android
android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
My Android App

for ios
Just open it in xCode select project tab general just rename it.

Answer (score 6):

simply change `<string name="app_name"> 'NEW_APP_NAME' </string>`
 located in

> [project_dir]/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml

NOTE: recommended

> react-native-rename

by [Paul Nyondo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44697712/6498792) maybe affect MainApplication.java file, DON'T USE IT!

Comment: Agreed, I had isntall react-native-rename and it does another problem in APP

Answer (score 5):

```
Change the name at \android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml,  
app.jon, and ./android/app/src/main/java/MainActivity.java
```

```
    **strings.xml**
    <resources>
        <string name="app_name">NewAppName</string>
    </resources>
    
    **app.json**
    {
      "name": "NewAppName",
      "displayName": "NewAppName"
    }
    
    **MainActivity.java**
      @Override
      protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "NewAppName";
      }
```

Then run these commands on terminal

```
    cd android  
    ./gradlew clean   
    cd ..  
    npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 3):

before changing the app name get your code's backup and then , Go to following path in and replace your app name with new app name and change i one more file app.json
E:***\android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">New Name</string>
</resources>
```

app.json

```
{
  "name": "oldName",
  "displayName": "New Name"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the app name in

- \android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My App</string>
</resources>
```

-app.json

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "displayName": "My App"
}
```

-package.json

```
 "name": "My App",
```

-also have to change return "appName" from android/app/src/main/java/com/companyName/appName/MainActivity.java

```
@Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "My App"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

1. Update displayName in app.json to the new name
2. Delete ios/ and android/ directories
3. Run **react-native eject**
4. Run **react-native link**

Comment: eject seems not working if over React 0.6 upper, so the command show error: error Unrecognized command "eject".

Answer (score 2):

Simply way

**PROJECT >android > app > main > res > style**

Then change the app name

Answer (score 2):

To change the name of the react-native Application

1 .  Open ./android/app/src/main/java/[multiple folders]/MainActivity.java

```
 @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "NameOfTheApp";
  }
```

2. Open  android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml

   NEW APP NAME
3. Change Name in App.json and package.json.

4.For clean android project run following command

cd android &&./gradlew clean

Comment: After trying everything on the internet, this (step #1) was the thing that made everything work.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2023**
(React Native Version > 0.69)

The accepted answer works fine. However, there is a problem: all the built files are still based on the old name, which will cause unpredicted issues.
So my suggestion is to delete ios and android folders and regenerate them. Here are the steps to do so:

1. delete ios and android folders from the root directory

> `sudo rm -rf android/ ios/` (on Windows delete manually)

2. add react native eject package

> `yarn add react-native-eject`

3. change the name of app in package.json and app.json to your desired new name
4. regenrate ios and android folders

> `npx react-native eject`

5. link installed modules in ios

> `cd ios && pod install`

6. create a new android build (root directory)

> `react-native run-android`

7. create a new ios build (root directory)

> `react-native run-ios`

**NOTE:**
By following this approach you will lose icons and fonts that are already added to your project! However, in my opinion it totally worth it, because you solve this issue once and for all.

Comment: Worked for me building for Android. In step 3 I also updated package-lock.json. I didn’t need step 5 but please could you clarify what this involves in case I need to build for iOS?

Comment: Some libraries rely on native code, in that case you'll have to add these files to your app, otherwise the app will throw an error as soon as you try to use the library. "pod install" makes sure these native modules are linked  to your react-native app.

Comment: Oh I see now what you meant. There needs to be a semi colon after cd ios;  I thought you meant to cd into three directories and do something, but now I see that pod install is the second command. Would be better to have the two commands on two separate lines perhaps.

Comment: It works perfectly. A very safe way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**first of all create a whole backup of the project *including node modules*  (in order to restore icons/phots ..etc in the future)**

1. Update name and displayName in app.json to the new name
2. rename app folder the same as app name
3. Delete ios/ and android/ directories
4. delete ndoe modules
5. update name in package.json (you must use new name for import & require() in your code. eg : import {x} from 'NewAppName/src/api')
6. watchman watch-del-all
7. rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*
8. rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*
9. restart pc
10. sudo npm install
11. react-native eject
12. restore icons/images
13. react-native link
14. restart pc
15. run app
    **caution : you may have to setup things manually. in my case SplashScreen**

Comment: very complicated not simple

Answer (score 1):

Changed my app name in android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml as:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My App</string>
</resources>
```

and re-run using npx react-native run-android

Answer (score 1):

The generator does not override the strings.xml file located in android/app/src/main/res/values/, so you have to change the app_name variable manually

And then run this command in android of root directory.

- Mac

  > .\gradlew clean
- Window

  > gradlew clean

and run in root direcoty
> npm run android

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to [Chhay Rith Hy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10910818/chhay-rith-hy) answer

If you are using Windows, you should use backslash or else you'll get an error "'.' is not recognized as internal or external command(...)"

So, instead of doing:

`./gradlew clean`

You should do:

`.\gradlew clean`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).