# React Native Task :app:validateSigningDebug FAILED

Tags: react-native

I am completely new to react-native and android. I have downloaded a project from Github and used commands `yarn install` and `react-native run-android` to run the project. but getting this error. Can't seem to understand the reason. What should I do?

```
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
17 actionable tasks: 17 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'.
> Keystore file '/home/tawsif/react native/react-native-redux/android/app/debug.keystore' not found for signing config 'debug'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51610775/11212074 Please refer

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The problem is that the build is looking for the debug keystore and cannot find it.

> Keystore file `/home/tawsif/react native/react-native-redux/android/app/debug.keystore` not found for signing config 'debug'.

There's an issue with the same problem in React Native GitHub. According to the page, you can solve it by creating a debug keystore. Quote from the thread:

> You can generate the debug keystore by running this command in the
> `android/app/` directory: `keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

Link to the issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25629

Comment: Thank you very much. The link really helped. I will post the solution as an answer for the beginners

Answer (score 27):

Just download from official template https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react-native/master/template/android/app/debug.keystore

Copy `debug.keystore` into your `android/app/`.

Ex:
`mv ~/Downloads/debug.keystore /Users/lazaro/apps/myapp/android/app/`

ref: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25629#issuecomment-513245590

Comment: this solution will help you avoid the "this file has been tampered with or password is incorrect" error

Answer (score 14):

Based on @rabbit87's answer the solution is running the following command inside 
`ProjectName/Andoid/app` directory solves the problem

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Answer (score 5):

I was having same error, It was solved by this https://coderwall.com/p/r09hoq/android-generate-release-debug-keystores

do

> cd ./android/app/

and then

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

Comment: It is best practice to include a description of the solution in case the link changes or goes dead.

Comment: It's Done.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ‘:app:validateSigningDebug’. > Keystore file ‘debug.keystore’ not found for signing config ‘debug’.

**debug keystore is missing in your android/app directory**

- First I installed all of my node packages with npm

  **$ npm install**
- After installing all of my node dependencies I then attempted to run the app for the first time and ran into the error message described above. My first attempt at fixing the problem involved attempting to reinstall all of my native Android dependencies with gradle…

  **$ cd android**

  **$ ./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies**

  **$ ./gradlew clean**
- Next, I attempted to create a new debug.keystore file myself using the following terminal commands:

  **$ cd android/app**

  **$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000**

Answer (score 2):

your project is missing the keystore to debug env

see [this answer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25629#issuecomment-513245590) on github

add debug.keystore to android/app directory

don't forget to add it to .gitignore

android/app/debug.keystore

Answer (score 0):

npm I jetifier
npx jetify

Fixed it for me on react-native 0.60.0

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting this error, too...to fix it:

1. create a new project using the `Basic Activity` template (but any template probably works)

   - in `Android Studio` > `File` > `New` > `New Project...` > `Basic Activity` > `Next` > re-name if needed > `Finish`
2. after builds, run the app on a device/emulator
3. now, run broken project we are trying to fix, and it should be working (tada!)