# React native rename error - app keeps stopping

Tags: android, react-native

I am using [react-native-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename) to rename my project. When I build my app I get the error, `App keeps stopping`.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Logcat gives me an error:

> 2020-01-16 10:21:25.792 9881-9881/uk.nhs.dgft.tc E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity **uk.nhs.dgft.tc.MainActivity** has leaked window DecorView@f512995[] that was originally added here
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:485)
>           at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:346)
>           at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
>           at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:330)
>           at org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:36)
>           at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6184)
>           at org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen.show(SplashScreen.java:27)
>           at org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen.show(SplashScreen.java:49)
>           at org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen.show(SplashScreen.java:56)
>           at uk.nhs.dgft.tc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

MainActivity:

```
package uk.nhs.dgft.tc;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity
{

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        SplashScreen.show(this);  // here
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName()
    {
        return "tcapp";
    }

    @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate()
    {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName())
        {
            @Override
            protected ReactRootView createRootView()
            {
                return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794679/change-app-name-in-react-native

Comment: @bomber sorry to say but i guess its a very bad library. many users have reported the issue of project getting crashed.  please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37389905/change-package-name-for-android-in-react-native and see second answer and also the comments