# What are the sizes required for React-Native app icons?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm pretty confused about the requirements for app icons.

I see this in the Xcode interface for applying app icon sizes:

[image: App Icon interface]

From what I can tell, these are different sizes for different iPhone screens. I'm not clear as to what 2x and 3x represent. Also, from Apple's guides:

[image: Apple resolution guide]

Those sizes don't seem to match up with what Xcode is asking for or suggesting. I've seen other answers regarding this on Stack Overflow but the interface for setting the App Icons is different.

I just want a definitive guide on exactly what should be going on in Xcode in regards to app icons for React Native.

Edit: This question was asked here [How to add icons to React Native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329715/how-to-add-icons-to-react-native-app)

but the interface from back then (Dec 2015) is different from the interface I see now.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: @Chiquis the problem is that it's proposing a bunch of sizes that Xcode isn't asking for. If you look at the screenshot provided on that question, the interface doesn't look the same at all. It looks much easier to understand. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I can't see the interface you are referring to, however the one in your screenshot is the standard one. Those empty spaces at the top are each of the icons that Xcode wants. If you want to see the actual required size in pixels (not points) click on it. It will be shown on the details to the right. Size and scale. iPhone screens is either x2 or x3 (nowadays) so make an icon of 40 pixels for the [Size 20 scale 2x] and the same in 60 pixels for the [size 20 scale 3x] then just drag them to each of the boxes. None that some have similar "pixel sizes" when multiplied so just re-use those.

Comment: @Chiquis got it! Thank you so much