# How to generate new image asset in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

All the documentation refers to right clicking on the res folder, choosing new and selecting "new Image Asset" - this option is simply not there. I've tried looking around for it and can't find it anywhere. What am I missing?

Here's what I see:

[image]

Comment: Answer if using React Native - install node with sudo:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63073599/10247962

Comment: This solution worked for me -- https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3512#issuecomment-516252436

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please install missing platform(s) just click on the link and wait for a while to install or download then new Image assit and new vector asset will apear.

Comment: Kinda sad that this person got downvoted so much when in fact it is the correct answer for the OP: you can see at the bottom of the screenshot the link "Install missing platform(s)" which was the issue causing gradle sync to fail.

Comment: That's stack overflow in a nutshell

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue for some time here.

My issue was that I opened the project in Android Studio pointing the wrong folder.
I work in a React Native project and opened the root folder of the project.

The problem was solved after I opened my project in Android Studio pointing to the Android folder inside my React Native project. Then, Android Studio synced the Android project in fact the the option showed up! :)

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Did not work for me. I too have a react native project but I did open android studio in the android folder. However, the option is still missing.

Answer (score 14):

The correct answer to this appears to be to update Gradle. I installed the above plugins, no luck. I ran updates on Android Studio, no luck. It was only after Android Studio asked me to update Gradle, and then the project resynced, that I saw the `Image Asset` option.

Answer (score 12):

Go to File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Then android studio may ask you to upgrade Gradle and once done, you will be able to see the option for New > Image Asset

Comment: There is no 'Sync Project with Gradle Files' for me in the 'File' menu...

Comment: If you can't find the sync option, double click build.gradle in your android project and click 'Open for editing in Android Studio' (mainly in a flutter project). This will automatically update and sync your project.

Answer (score 8):

had the same issue.
You are missing a plugin named **Android Drawable Importer**.

Go to *File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories*
Search for the missing plugin, install and restart Android Studio.

The option for Image Asset should be available after that.

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to add an image for the steps.

Comment: I had high hopes for this, but it didn't work for me. The menu option is still missing.

Comment: This is not correct. Android Drawable Importer is unrelated to the Image Asset Studio

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same on Android Studio 3 with the plugin `Android Drawable Importer` already installed from the plugin respository, and I also needed to update Gradle, which in my case meant updating the build tools by clicking the link in the message that looked like this

```
Failed to find Build Tools revision 27.0.3
Install Build Tools 27.0.3 and sync project
```

After an install, and then a lengthy update where Gradle was updating itself and downloading in the background tasks window.  I then could see the options for File > New > Image Asset

Answer (score 0):

I am writing my **React Native** project, and for me has been worked this way:

1. Open **Android Studio**
2. Select **Import Gradle Project** from pop up window
3. Wait **Android Studio** to finish **sync build**
4. After all press second click to **res** folder -> **New** -> **Image Asset**

Answer (score -1):

Creating a brand new project helped in my case

old project
[image]

new flutter project

[image]