# Android Studio Image Asset Launcher Icon Background Color

Tags: android, background

I have a .png logo for my app which doesn't have a background, when I add it to android studio as an Image Asset I am forced to have a background. The hex field doesn't accept 8 digit color codes, 6 digits only. Is there anyway to keep the background invisible?

Comment: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ Great tool for any type of icons you want to generate

Answer (score 214, accepted):

To make background transparent, set `shape` as `None`.
See the image below:

[image]

EDIT:

For Android Studio 3.0,
you can set it from `Legacy` Tab

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't notice that I needed to scroll down to see shape :)

Comment: just select image radio button and scroll down...thanks worked for me

Comment: How do you get to the above window from android studio

Comment: @gikarasojokinene Follow this path: res->new->Image Asset

Comment: Yet another example of the poor UX in Studio

Comment: How to make the background layer transparent?

Comment: It seems you need to use Patrick's answer below for Android Studio 3+.

Comment: after creating app icon has empty borders to remove that @ElYeante

Comment: On newer Android Studio versions the tab is called "Options".

Comment: The `Legacy` option is not available in the latest Android Studio: Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335, built on September 30, 2022

Answer (score 47):

I'm using `Android Studio 3.0.1` and if the above answer doesn't work for you, try to change the `icon type` into `Legacy` and select `Shape` to `None`, the default one is `Adaptive and Legacy`.

[image]

Note: Some device has installed a launcher with automatically adding white background in icon, that's normal.

Comment: You select legacy only when your targetSdkVersion is less than 26. If your targetSdkVersion is 26, then your icon type should be adaptive and legacy.

Comment: How to make the background layer transparent?

Comment: @zulkarnainshah if you choose to shape none with the legacy mode, then it will show transparent colour.

Comment: Does not seem to work in Android Studio 3+.  However, Patrick's answer below does seem to work, at least in Android Studio 3.1.2.

Comment: @StephenM - which Android version your running? Remember that things become different specially from icon starting from Lollipop to the latest Android version, so I would not be surprise if people seing different background icon in the latest Android version. the fix is to try to use the lower version of Android and use a launcher that doesn't add any background in icons just for development to see the real design of your icon or stick on using the latest Android and just follow what they want.

Comment: @Polar - I'm using Android Studio 3.1.2 and building with target and compile SDK versions set at 26 and min SDK version at 23.  What do you mean by lower version of Android?  Android Studio or target/compile/min SDK version?

Answer (score 34):

You have two ways:

1) In *Background Layer > Scaling*, reduce the **Resize** to **1**

[image]

and then in *Legacy > Legacy Icon* set **Shape** as **None**

[image]

---

2) in *Background Layer > Scaling > Source Asset*, you can set an image as a 1x1 pixel (or any size) transparent.png image (you've already created).

[image]

and then in *Legacy > Legacy Icon* set **Shape** as **None**

[image]

Comment: what did you do about `Full Bleed Layers`?

Answer (score 25):

This is just another workaround.

1. For the 'Foreground Layer', select 'Asset type' as text and delete the default text in the text field.

[image: Browse to your image path]

2. For the 'Background Layer', select 'Asset type' as image and now choose the path of the image you want as an icon.

[image]

And you are good to go.

Comment: Very simple solution. Big Thanks! I've tested it on Android Studio 3.6 and one thing to add is that it was giving me the error upon having Foreground text null. So what I had done is just adding a space there and it's working. And adding some more! after that I got one problem that when I finished adding mipmap and ran my project, there was an Android logo overriding my logo and I fixed that by modifying mipmap icon xml files by removing there foreground tag line. Hope it will help someone.

Comment: This is brilliant!

Comment: and set shape to none too.. working on android studio 4.1.1

Answer (score 24):

the above approach didn't work for me on Android Studio 3.0.  It still shows the background.  I just made an empty background file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector
android:height="108dp"
android:width="108dp"
android:viewportHeight="108"
android:viewportWidth="108"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</vector>
```

This worked except the full bleed layers

Comment: I'm also using Android Studio 3.0, I do the same to make it work. Looks like we are no longer allow to make an icon base on what we want.

Comment: This is not working. Android Studio 3.0.1, You can't set a transparent background.

Comment: Worked for me in Android Studio 3.1.2.  It showed up in the Image Asset generator as black, but it is transparent when I deploy my app.

Comment: I get a rendering error when I try using this vector as the background, anyone else?

Comment: I think you should add path inside the vector.

Answer (score 8):

Android Studio 3.5.3 
It works with this configuration.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I Just put my view background (color code) as ClipArt or Image background, and it looks like transparent or no background where both have the same color as background.

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I took to make an image transparent:

1- I used an online website which makes the image transparent, there are a lot of them. For me, I use this https://www241.lunapic.com/editor/?action=transparent and sometimes this https://www.online-image-editor.com/help/transparency

2- In Android Studio (I'm using version 3.1.3), open Image Asset from app > res (right click) > New > Image Asset
[image: Image Asset]

3- In the Path, choose the location of the transparent image which you downloaded from the online website, and make the other options as shown, then Next, then Finish. The five different sizes of image mdpi(48×48), hdpi(72×72), xhdpi(96×96), xxhdpi(144×144), and xxxhdpi(192×192) will be created in the **res/mipmap-*density*** folders.
[image: Image Asset Configuration]

4- If you need sizes (dimensions) different from above, you can use this website https://nsimage.brosteins.com/ to upload your PNG image of biggest size that will be used in xxxhdpi. After uploading, you can download a zip file containing the five different sizes of image in the **res/drawable-*density*** folders.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, create a launcher icon `(Adaptive and Legacy)` from Image Asset:

Select an `image` for background layer and resize it to 0% or 1% and
In legacy tab set `shape` to `none`.

Then, delete folder `res/mipmap/ic_laucher_round` in the project window and Open AndroidManifest.xml and remove attribute `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` from the `application` element.

In the end, delete `ic_launcher.xml` from `mipmap-anydpi-v26`.

Notice that: Some devices like Nexus 5X (Android 8.1) adding a white background automatically and can't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

With "Asset Type" set to "Image", try setting the same image for the foreground and background layers, keeping the same "Resize" percentage.

Answer (score 1):

I just added the icon as a normal icon: New -> Vector Asset

and then change the app icon in the Manifest file.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work for me.  The emulator and a samsung galaxy both still show white backgrounds.  The svg file definitely used clear background (or none at all).

Answer (score 0):

For Foreground Layer choose "Text" and then delete the content text
Finaly choose the path of the image you want as an icon.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaD3v.png)

Comment: Hi, your answer is fairly recent and lately I cannot find my way to the Asset Image Studio.  Does it still exist, and how do I get there if "yes" please?

Comment: Hi, yes it still exist

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I can't remember the source now but I followed instructions and found it.

Comment: You need to select the image option (Asset type) first and you will see the field to select the icon image path.

Comment: OK, You're welcome mathems32.

Answer (score -1):

Using android 3.0.1
I noticed this weird behavior(solution),
First: in background layer in the source_asset change the asset_type from image to color and than change it back to image.
second: enable trim in scaling and then resize it to a small percentage and it will work perfectly.
PS: If u didn't do the first step the scaling wont take affect.
and if anyone have an explanation for this please provide. 
[steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uHHI.jpg)