# New Image Asset Launcher Icon Loss of Transparency

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, png, android-assets

I am trying to add a launcher icon for an app in Android Studio.

What I've done so far:

Gone to `res` folder right click and select `new image asset`

From there I find the png file which I would like to use as the app launcher icon.

This step is seen here: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxYNr.png

As you can see, the source asset is displayed correctly, with no white background. But the 5 different icon types have a white background and lose their transparency.

I would like for the app icon to retain its transparency and not show a white background.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make background transparent, set `shape` as `None`. See the image below:

***Before***

[image: Before]

***After***

[image: After]

Comment: how it's possible in android studio 2.3.1?

Comment: Same question related to Visual Studio?

Comment: In AS 3.1 a dialog changed, so move to Legacy icons, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48008091/2914140.