# Transparent adaptive icon background

Tags: android

So I have been working on this app for a couple weeks and I started to build the icon. I have Android Studio 3.0.1 and they seem to have changed the way Image Assets are made, now they have adaptive icons. I made an icon with transparent background for my app. Before, I would just change the shape to "none" and there would be no background generated. But now that is not an option unless I go to "legacy" which is useless. The background color does not seem to support transparency. Even if in the `ic_launcher.xml` I set the background to a transparent color but the icon still appears with a black background.

Here is my `ic_lancher.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

And ic_launcher_round.xml is the same. The `@color/transparent` bit is a this:

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

Comment: Did you check this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085753/android-studio-image-asset-launcher-icon-background-color and https://medium.com/google-developers/implementing-adaptive-icons-1e4d1795470e

Comment: Yes, none of those really helped

Comment: as in the link provided above by @InsaneCat: "background drawables must be opaque whilst foregrounds can contain transparency." Unfortunately this is no where clear in the documentation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**TL;DR** Adaptive Icons cannot have transparent Background

### Transparent background will be opaque black.

According to the source code of Android 8.0 framework, the `<background>` layer is inherently opaque; the framework fills the background with opaque black, as mentioned in the question.

The framework has a class `AdaptiveIconDrawable`, which draws adaptive launcher icons.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AdaptiveIconDrawable.html
The element `<adaptive-icon>` creates an instance of it:

> This class can also be created via XML inflation using `<adaptive-icon>` tag in addition to dynamic creation.

[The source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-release/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/AdaptiveIconDrawable.java#351) of method `draw` in `AdaptiveIconDrawable.java` is:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mLayersBitmap == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (mLayersShader == null) {
        mCanvas.setBitmap(mLayersBitmap);
        mCanvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i = 0; i < mLayerState.N_CHILDREN; i++) {
            if (mLayerState.mChildren[i] == null) {
                continue;
            }
            final Drawable dr = mLayerState.mChildren[i].mDrawable;
            if (dr != null) {
                dr.draw(mCanvas);
            }
        }
        mLayersShader = new BitmapShader(mLayersBitmap, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
        mPaint.setShader(mLayersShader);
    }
    if (mMaskBitmap != null) {
        Rect bounds = getBounds();
        canvas.drawBitmap(mMaskBitmap, bounds.left, bounds.top, mPaint);
    }
}
```

In short, a [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) instance receives a bitmap to draw into, and initially it fills the bitmap with black color. Then the foreground drawable and the background drawable do the job:

```
mCanvas.setBitmap(mLayersBitmap); // reset
mCanvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);   // fill
for (int i = 0; i < mLayerState.N_CHILDREN; i++) { // two layers
    ...
    final Drawable dr = mLayerState.mChildren[i].mDrawable;
    ...
        dr.draw(mCanvas); // draw
    ...
}
```

The [Color.BLACK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#BLACK) is opaque:

> 0xff000000

The method [drawColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawColor%28int%29) fills the bitmap with it, using [SRC_OVER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html#SRC_OVER) mode:

> Fill the entire canvas' bitmap (restricted to the current clip) with the specified color, using srcover porterduff mode.

So, the background will be always opaque, even if you set transparent color to the background, as in the screenshot below (from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49667272/9298629) to a similar question).

[image: NoAdaptive and Adaptive]

Comment: how to make it white?

Comment: It will be white, if you set `<color name="transparent">#ffffffff</color>` in "res/values/color.xml" for `@color/transparent`, as in the question.

Comment: @Dika Some launcher apps such as [Pixel Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher) will change the background color of launcher icons to white, as I wrote in "Update #2" section in [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49667272/9298629).

Comment: Why Android is trying to imitate iOS by removing the good features of itself?!

Answer (score 11):

**Easiest Solution ever:**

1. Assuming you have a PNG file with a transparent background (preferably, square ratio), let's call it "app_icon.png", put it in your *drawable* folder
   P.S: It doesn't matter how large it is, what matters is the square ratio.
2. Go to AndroidManifest.xml, in your main application tag, check for the

   android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"

and change it to

```
android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
```

3. Delete all your "mipmap" folders now since you don't need them.

Why does this work: This tells android to use a drawable DIRECTLY from the folder as an icon, without going through the hurdle of mipmap XML files.

Congratulations, now you will have a logo with a transparent background.

Comment: This is the real answer I'm looking for. Thanks Arya Danesh. You save my time.

Comment: Please somebody explain why this answer, which in two lines explain how to solve the issue, is down here.

Answer (score 1):

You said a legacy icon is "useless", but the only logical solution is to use a legacy icon. If you don't create an adaptive icon at all, Android 8.0 and above will have to use a legacy icon. Moreover, an adaptive icon with a transparent background is a contradictory concept because the main feature of an adaptive icon is that the foreground is contained within a shape determined by the OEM. But if the background is transparent, how can there be any shape? You might as well be asking how to square a circle.

Answer (score 0):

Generate your launcher icons using Android Studio with a transparent XML background layer, then delete `ic_launcher.xml` and `ic_launcher_round.xml` from `res/mipmap-anydpi-v26` (the ones with the black background). Android will then have to fallback on one of the other versions (hdpi, etc.) with a transparent background.

Answer (score -5):

just play with 8 digit hex code
example : 80DCDCDC im using this for a long time for transparency