# App icon not displaying when application goes to background

Tags: android

Application icon not displaying when app goes to background. Instead app icon it shows default android icon. Although i added app icon with transparent  background . Any help is appreciated .[image]

Manifest File :

```
<application
    android:name=".TeenApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Can you add your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: `ic_launcher` is your app icon or **default android icon**?

Comment: its my app's icon

Comment: Check all the **mipmap** folder. probably you missed something

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio Image Asset Launcher Icon Transparent Background Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597773/android-studio-image-asset-launcher-icon-transparent-background-color)

Comment: Any solutions??

Answer (score 1):

Remove `ic_launcher_foreground.xml` from `drawable-v24` folder

```
/res/drawable-v24/ic_launcher_foreground.xml
```

The image should be like this:

[image]

Comment: @Richa, check the answer

Comment: its not in drawable-24 , its in mipmaps

Comment: `.xml` or `.png`?

Comment: its xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <adaptive-icon xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <background android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_background"/> <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/> </adaptive-icon>

Comment: Remove all the icon like above. In my case it's in `drawable-v24`

Comment: Probably you need clean build, try it

Comment: i did it, but what i came to know, somehow foreground xml is not working. if i remove that line its showing proper bg as soon as i try to put foreground, it is showing android default icon.

Comment: **it is showing android default icon** from where? It means in your project has that icon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205910/discussion-between-richa-and-md-asaduzzaman).

Comment: To those who are facing problem like this, Check your bg xml and ic_launcher_round, fixed issue by altering them. +1 Md. Asaduzzaman for help.

Answer (score 0):

From Android Nougat, default launcher icon should be `roundIcon`. See this [Reference](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1.html)

You have to add it in your `AndroidManifest` for your `application` tag

```
 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
 android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

Comment: Check in the res folder if you have not forget default icon, like in `drawable-v4` or `mipmap-anydpi-v26`

Comment: in anydpi-v26 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>

Comment: where, ic_launcher_bg has some solid image, do you think it can create problem ?