# Android Studio - Asset Studio doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating to Android Studio 3.3, I can't add Launcher Icons (Legacy)  by clicking `Image Asset` on project's file tree. No matter what picture, no matter format I use, it always displays a white space.
Any ideas on how to encounter this problem?

It looks like this
[image: Showcase of the bug]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any official fixes available so far. We can use a version like 3.2 or older.

EDIT: 
The fix will is included in Android Studio 3.4 Beta 2, Android Studio 3.3.1 and newer

[(source)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122133551)

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the yellow triangle >>
Down and to the left of the image.
Make sure there is no other file with the same name.

Comment: It completely doesn't matter, I tried changing name :/

Comment: Try to set the Shape as None

Comment: @Baftek Check this:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37085753/10470283)
It might help.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in Android Studio 3.3, and it has already been notified in the Issue Tracker:

[Issue: 122995873](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122995873)

Comment: Thank you. I'm gonna work on Beta Channel. It's currently v3.4 Beta 1 so should work quite well