# image asset problem (Background Problem) - what should I do?

Tags: android

[image]

I have recently updated Android Studio 3.4 to 3.5 which fixes things. Now, what happened is in 3.4 version I could able to make my image background transparent which selecting shape none. Now I could not able to do that in 3.5 version.

Please help me to fix this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My step to solve this situation.

1. Access : https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html
2. Go to Launcher Icon Generator
3. Select image and switch shape to None
4. You'll got transparent image asset
5. Download and copy to your Android Studio Res Folder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PQgU.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PQgU.png)

Comment: It looks like that it's an Android Studio issue, isn't there any fix to this problem without using "romannurik" image asset generator site? It is much more efficient and faster to add an image asset from Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

You can select the same thing in android studio 3.5, just make sure to choose the proper Icon type as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Nope, still not working. How do I achieve background transparent?

Comment: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085753/android-studio-image-asset-launcher-icon-background-color)