# Android: display icon in the application

Tags: android, android-studio

It does not display the icon in the application, what to do?

I tried to add this way, but it did not work.

With this method, only changed the application icon in the menu.

[image]

Comment: try with other new icons and rebuild the project

Comment: You need to use custom layout for your actionbar or toolbar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application/5350771#5350771

Comment: I tried to put a different icon and rebuild project, added the manifest line with the addition of icon. But it did not help me. How use custom layout? @Drv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no.1 change bar to toolbar then

```
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

no.3
mainfest->change icon

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: This partly helped me, now there is a home button, when I move to another layout. But still it does not show icon. @Cgx

Answer (score 1):

Create toolbar_actionbar.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_back"
        android:text="Weather"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Add the above layout in your main layout file by using below lines:

```
 <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></include>
```

In your style, write below lines in your parent theme:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

And add below lines to your activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

ImageButton imgbtn=(ImageButton)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.imgBtn);
```