# Xamarin Android | Application Icon Error. Cant set one

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, icons

Im new to Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin and created a App with a Webview in it. My script works when I test it on my device but I just cant add in Icon to it!

I read a lot about it and spend hours trying! I figured out i had to add the Icon to the assemblyInfo like this `[assembly: Application(Icon = "@drawable/icon")]`
After adding this I always get an Error:

> Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon').  Test    ...\obj\Debug\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml  8

But i put an Image in my drawable folder (icon.png) ! I also cant see the icon on the sidebar in my Project folder in Visual Studio..

Some how I figured out that I can add the icon.png file to obj/Debug/res/drawable after I created the fodler drawable there and it will show the Icon on my Android BUT then my App doesnt work anymore -> Blackscreen and the App crashes.

Why is it so hard to add a god damn Icon? I also cant select any Icon in my Properties Tab like its shown in the Tutorial

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/#Specify_the_Application_Icon.

The DropDown "Application Icon" is always empty no matter how I try to add my Icon. Thats how it looks on my screen:
[Picture of Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVe4w.png)

Please help me!

Comment: follow this link maybe it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately not. I allready knew this Post because I read hunderts of them due my problem :/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you  just do this on your first activity where MainLuncher is true

```
 [Activity(Label = "MainActivity", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon_you_want")]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        //...
    }
```

And remove that `[assembly: Application(Icon = "@drawable/icon")]` form AssemblyInfo.cs

The dropdown will still remain empty but you will see the image.