# In Xamarin Forms (Android and IOS) how can I reset the app icon to the Xamarin default icon?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I want to start all the theme and style customization from scratch.

In Android, I tried to replace the whole Resources folder for one that I generated with a blank Android app but I got several errors saying resources files were not found.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Xamarin Forms (Android and IOS) how can I reset the app icon to the Xamarin default icon?

**Xamarin.Android :**

You need copy your icon to [Resource\Drawable...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application) folder,  after all the icons are copied to the `Xamarin.Android` project, **open the Android Manifest** by right clicking on the properties of your Project Solution.

Select `Android Manifest`  and select `@drawable/yourIcon` from the `Application icon`.

[image]

**Xamarin.iOS :**

You could refer to the official documents : [Xamarin.iOS Application Icons](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/app-icons/).

**EDIT :**

You could download the [Xamarin Android Icon](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/Resources/XamarinAndroidIcons.zip), put them in `Resource\Drawable` or `Resource\mipmap` folder, then select `@drawable\icon` from the Application icon combo box:

[image]

For more detail information, you could read the [document](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/#Walkthrough), you could see how to set icon at step 24. **Then your project  will  have the original Xamarin icon**.

Comment: thanks, but how to reset to the original Xamarin icon?

Comment: @joseluisgonzalezclua, I  have update my answer, please check it.