# Setting up Android App Icon for the release APK

Tags: android, icons, release

Can someone help me understand how I can set the App Icon for the release APK? I was able to set it in the APK that I run from android studio. But it is not reflecting in the release APK.

Comment: `it is not reflecting in the release APK` can you explain more about this. current what happened with your release APK icon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set icon for Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application)

Answer (score 1):

in your manifest :

```
<application
        android:name=".Main.Services.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/yourIcon"
        android:label="@string/label"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/yourIcon"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:allowClearUserData="false"
        tools:targetAPI="19"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click on App folder > new > Image Asset > Set up your icon.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the app icon in the Android application required changes in manifest.xml file

In Manifest file under application tag use 
android: icon=" path to the image icon file"
Android:roundIcon="path to the image icon file" // required for latest android versions.
Note:- You must have to provide both icons in order to make the icon file visible on all android versions.