# Where is the "Add Image Asset" to create an Android Icon?

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

I can't find a way to add an icon.

I read that you can right click and create a new Image Asset. But it can't be found on the latest version of Android Studio.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34331879/179736

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to navigate to `.app/src/main` first - not directly to `.app`.
Then right-click on `res` folder and you will be able to add your image asset
[check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL0Gr.png)

Comment: If you have a screenshot of this behavior, that would be a valuable addition to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

click on main menus ---> file ---> new ----> ImageAsset , like this :

[image]

or right click on res folder and new Image Asset :

[image]