# Android launcher icon only appears in the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, icons

I'm trying to add a launcher icon to my android app. I have watched multiple tutorials online that explain how that works. I ended up doing it this way:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQ8HDL-X9rM

The laucher icon does appears in the android simulator but not on physical phones.
what I have tried to do:

- clean the build in android studio
- reset the icon the way it says in the tutorial
- checked the reference in android manifest
- checked if the icon was changed in the drawable and mipmap folders

that were the tips that showed up in a stackoverflow topic a couple years back.
I have been working on it for the passed week and I just can't get it to work.

This is my ic_launcher.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/>
   <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

And this is this are the lines in my AndroidManifest

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"

        <activity android:name="com.example.fragments.Product">
           <meta-data
              android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
              android:value="com.example.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.MainActivity">
           <intent-filter>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Also I checked all the mipmap folders and all my icons are in there with the correct names.

Does anyone know what I can do?

---update june 3---

Now its not even showing up on the emulator anymore...
I have tried and read all the topics online I really hope someone can spot what I do wrong

Comment: Does your main activity in the manifest have an `intent-filter` with `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>`?

Comment: Yes. It is inside the <activity MainActivity> It was in the wrong order then the <category you send so I changed that but It didn't help

Comment: Please post the entry for your entry point activity in the manifest.

Comment: I am new to android developing so I dont know exactly what you mean so I posted the entire AndroidManifest file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple way to add icon for app

go to project
app->res->drawable->right click->new->image asset-> source asset
select image path and click to next button
RUN the app

[another way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10817936/12709358)

Comment: I dont know if you will ever believe me but I have tried that literally more then 5 times... But now after your reaction I did it again and it works. Thank you very much!! I did always click on app -> res -> mipmap instead of drawable. Maybe that was the problem?