# How to set an icon after eject of Expo app?

Tags: react-native, expo, icons, splash-screen

I've ejected Expo app to get bare workflow (to archive IAPs).

But now I need to change app icon and splash screen.

I see **tons** of different size images in **android/app/src/main/res/**. Any change to `app.json` does not make sense (probably this is fine as far I use `eas-cli` to build it).

Is there some easy way do change an icon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set icon for Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application)

Comment: Also take a look at [it](https://medium.com/@appstud/add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-810492e773f9)

Comment: Thanks for links, but I mostly try to find some automated solution, like in Expo before ejecting project, because this is not only about icons, but also about splash screens. Probably I will switch to not ejected (managed workflow) branch, generate all resources and then merge with ejected branch.

Answer (score 4):

After some research I've found that there are no tools for automated icon change.

But if you go into branch until you detached (ejected) Expo, you can set icon there in `assets` dir, then make `expo eject` (it will also generate icons and splash screens in different resolutions) and copy required files:

- `android/app/src/res` - for Android
- `ios/%app-name%/Images.xcassets` - for iOS

Keeping the point before detaching Expo as separate branch/tag is good practice regarding Expo docs, this is one of the cases where it can be useful.